# Updating Wagon's FindAllCrossings2D[] function

Tags: programming, numerics, equation-solving

Stan Wagon's *Mathematica in Action* (second edition; I haven't read the third edition and I'm hoping to eventually see it), demonstrates [a nifty function called `FindAllCrossings2D[]`](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=vpYmj7ohofsC&pg=PA289). What the function basically does is to augment `FindRoot[]` by using `ContourPlot[]` to find crossings that `FindRoot[]` can subsequently polish. [Here](http://stanwagon.com/wagon/Misc/HTMLLinks/SIAMchallenge_6.html), Wagon uses the function to assist in solving one of the questions of the SIAM hundred-digit challenge.

`ContourPlot[]` changed quite a bit starting from version 6 (e.g., it now outputs `GraphicsComplex[]` objects), and `FilterRules[]` has superseded the old standby `FilterOptions[]` With these in mind, I set out to update `FindAllCrossings2D[]`:

```
Options[FindAllCrossings2D] = 
  Sort[Join[Options[FindRoot], {MaxRecursion -> Automatic, 
     PerformanceGoal :> $PerformanceGoal, PlotPoints -> Automatic}]];

FindAllCrossings2D[funcs_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, {y_, ymin_, ymax_}, opts___] := 
 Module[{contourData, seeds, tt, fy = Compile[{x, y}, Evaluate[funcs[[2]]]]},

  contourData = Map[First, Cases[
     Normal[
      ContourPlot[funcs[[1]], {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax},
       Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> False, 
       PlotRange -> {Full, Full, Automatic}, 
       Evaluate[
        Sequence @@ 
         FilterRules[Join[{opts}, Options[FindAllCrossings2D]], 
          DeleteCases[Options[ContourPlot], Method -> _]]]
       ]], _Line, Infinity]];

  seeds = Flatten[Map[#[[
       1 + Flatten[Position[Rest[tt = Sign[Apply[fy, #, 2]]] Most[tt], -1]]
                ]] &, contourData], 1];

  If[seeds == {}, seeds,
   Select[
    Union[Map[{x, y} /. 
        FindRoot[{funcs[[1]] == 0, 
          funcs[[2]] == 0}, {x, #[[1]]}, {y, #[[2]]}, 
         Evaluate[
          Sequence @@ 
           FilterRules[Join[{opts}, Options[FindAllCrossings2D]], 
            Options[FindRoot]]]] &, 
      seeds]], (xmin < #[[1]] < xmax && ymin < #[[2]] < ymax) &]]]
```

The function works splendidly, it seems. I tried out the same example Wagon used in his book:

```
f[x_, y_] := -Cos[y] + 2 y Cos[y^2] Cos[2 x];
g[x_, y_] := -Sin[x] + 2 Sin[y^2] Sin[2 x];

pts = FindAllCrossings2D[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5},
                         Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}, 
                         PlotPoints -> 85, WorkingPrecision -> 20] // Chop;

ContourPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5},
        Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> False, 
        Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Red, Point /@ pts}]
```

[image: FindAllCrossings2D[] example]

Whew, that preamble was quite long. Here's my question, then:

> Are there "neater" (for some definition of "neater") ways to update/reimplement `FindAllCrossings2D[]` than my attempt?

Comment: Could someone come up with a Google Books link that works in Europe?

Comment: @Szabolcs What about this here http://books.google.de/books?id=vpYmj7ohofsC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: As a tiny note: one unexpected benefit of the `ContourPlot[]` approach is that one can exploit the `RegionFunction` option if one is only interested in roots within a given region.

Comment: @J.M. I just posted a new version using `ContourPlot[]` - seems very short.

Comment: I noticed, @Vitaliy; sadly I can't upvote again...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here is my latest code for this function, from Chapter 12 of the third edition of "Mathematica in Action". It is pretty short, but I will let you work out if it is faster or more robust than yours. Note the `PlotPoints` option for difficult cases.

```
FindRoots2D::usage = 
  "FindRoots2D[funcs,{x,a,b},{y,c,d}] finds all nontangential solutions to
   {f=0, g=0} in the given rectangle."; 

Options[FindRoots2D] = {PlotPoints -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> Automatic}; 

FindRoots2D[funcs_, {x_, a_, b_}, {y_, c_, d_}, opts___] := Module[
  {fZero, seeds, signs, fy}, 
  fy = Compile[{x, y}, Evaluate[funcs[[2]]]]; 

  fZero = Cases[Normal[
     ContourPlot[
        funcs[[1]] == 0, 
        {x, a-(b-a)/97, b+(b-a)/103}, {y, c-(d-c)/98, d+(d-c)/102}, 
        Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ContourPlot]]]]], 
     Line[z_] :> z, Infinity]; 

  seeds = Flatten[(
     (signs = Sign[Apply[fy, #1, {1}]]; 
      #1[[1 + Flatten[Position[Rest[signs*RotateRight[signs]], -1]]]]) &
     ) /@ fZero, 1];
  If[seeds == {}, {}, 
     Select[
        Union[({x, y} /.
           FindRoot[{funcs[[1]], funcs[[2]]}, {x, #1[[1]]}, {y, #1[[2]]}, 
              Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[FindRoot]]]] & ) /@ seeds, 
           SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^(-6) & )], 
        a <= #1[[1]] <= b && c <= #1[[2]] <= d & ]]]
```

Comment: Hi Dr. Wagon! Thanks for posting your updated code (and for the book in general; I hope I can get a copy of your new one some day); I'll do the tests later for this! I've also found that `RegionFunction` can be profitably used here to restrict the search to roots within a domain.

Comment: BTW: is there anything special about the increments chosen in `{x, a-(b-a)/97, b+(b-a)/103}, {y, c-(d-c)/98, d+(d-c)/102}`?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot remember exactly why I chose 97 and 103, but the reason is related to the effect that when things are too symmetric then there can be problems at the centers of symmetry. So it is best to add in a little asymmetry. Also I note that someone commented that some new Mathematica functions do some of these sorts of things..  but only for nice functions. If one had the Zeta function involved, say, then I do not believe their new algebraic ideas would work. Of course, since typical usages might be in DEs, finding equil. pts., it might be worth adding some cases to detect niceness.

Comment: Oh. Would you happen to have a set of equations on hand where the asymmetry in `ContourPlot[]` is a necessity?

Comment: Not on hand. But this function is used many many times in the VisualDSolve project to find equilibrium points for two autonomous DEs and I must have found some difficult examples there. Now, it is possible as Mathematica changes internally that some of the problems disappear. Let me mention that this function was able to solve one of the "100 Digit Challenge" problems in optimizing a complicated function of 2 vbles by finding all of the critical points in the region, and there were well over 2000 of them.

Comment: Oh yes, I linked to your page in the question where you used it on the SIAM challenge. Very nice!

Comment: There is a small problem with how the `Compile` arguments are being handled here.  With the setting `SetSystemOptions["StrictLexicalScoping" -> True];` this function fails due to `x` and `y` being renamed in `Compile[{x,y}, ...]` but not in `funcs`.

Answer (score 38):

This is `ContourPlot` based but seems much shorter:

```
FindCrossings2D[{f_, g_}, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, {y_, ymin_, ymax_}] := 
  {x, y} /. (FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {{x, #[[1]]}, 
  {y, #[[2]]}}] & /@ (ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, 
  {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}][[1, 1]]))
```

It works:

```
f[x_, y_] := -Cos[y] + 2 y Cos[y^2] Cos[2 x];
g[x_, y_] := -Sin[x] + 2 Sin[y^2] Sin[2 x];

pts = FindCrossings2D[{f, g}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5}];

ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 
  21/5}, Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Red, Point /@ pts}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice work! I'm amazed by so short codes.

Answer (score 34):

Let me give a different approach. `FindRoot` does a good job, but maybe we can calculate the seed-points in a different way. When you want to find the common roots of $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ you can transform the problem into one equation which has the same roots $$0=f(x,y)^2+g(x,y)^2$$
The nice property here, which I will use is that the right hand side of this equation is always greater than zero. The bad thing is, that functions that don't cross zero are kind of difficult for some numerical methods, but that will be no concern here.

When we look at our function and think of it as a kind of water-pool with a very low level of water, you would get something like this

[image]

Now the idea is to go around each of those small pools which have maybe one, maybe more local *zeroes* in it, and start from every coast point a root-search.

That's the time where the image-processing kicks in. Our function is always positive which gives a really nice image (I inverted gray-levels):

[image]

Cutting off the image at sea-level is just a binarization of the image.

[image]

Finding the coast-line of each pool is simply implemented by an image subtraction and a dilation of the binarized image.

[image]

The complete method is therefore to raster the above function, extract all coast-pixel with image processing and run `FindRoot` for each coast-point.

```
FindCrossings2D[{f_, g_}, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, {y_, ymin_, ymax_}, 
                 n_, threshold_] := Module[
{seeds = ImageData[ImageSubtract[Dilation[#, 1], #] &@
  Binarize[ColorNegate[Image[
         Table[f[x, y]^2 + g[x, y]^2, 
          {y, ymin, ymax, (ymax - ymin)/(n - 1.0)}, 
          {x, xmin, xmax, (xmax - xmin)/(n - 1.0)}]]], 
       threshold], "Bit"]},
  DeleteDuplicates[Last@Last@Reap[MapIndexed[
    If[#1 === 1, Sow[{x, y} /. FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, 
     {{x, Rescale[#2[[2]], {1, n}, {xmin, xmax}]},
      {y, Rescale[#2[[1]], {1, n}, {ymin, ymax}]}}]]] &, seeds, 2]
   ], (Norm[#1 - #2] < 10.^(-6)) &]
]
```

Here `n` is the raster-size and `thresh` is the binarization threshold which should be a bit smaller than 1.

```
f[x_, y_] := -Cos[y] + 2 y Cos[y^2] Cos[2 x];
g[x_, y_] := -Sin[x] + 2 Sin[y^2] Sin[2 x];

roots = FindCrossings2D[{f, g}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5}, 400, 0.8];
```

[image]

This approach has clearly the disadvantage of having a fixed raster size, while `ContourPlot` uses adaptive sampling. Nevertheless, for raster-sizes from 200-500 and thresholds from ?-0.95 the method finds all or at least many roots.

Comment: Interesting approach. When I tried `FindCrossings2D[{f, g}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5}, 400, 0.8]` on my system, it only got 59 out of the 67 roots within the region. (Increasing the value of the fourth argument gradually eventually yielded the roots, but takes quite a bit of time to execute.) I guess choosing appropriate parameters can be system-dependent...

Comment: For the record, the new-in-8 functions `ContourDetect` (and `CrossingDetect`) would come handy with this approach.

Answer (score 24):

You could use [`MorphologicalBranchPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MorphologicalBranchPoints.html) in combination with `ContourPlot` to find the seeds for the intersection points. Consider for example

```
f[x_, y_] := -Cos[y] + 2 y Cos[y^2] Cos[2 x];
g[x_, y_] := -Sin[x] + 2 Sin[y^2] Sin[2 x];

range = {{-7/2, 4}, {-9/5, 21/5}};
```

First we create a [binarized](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Binarize.html), thinned image of the contour plot.

```
binPlot = Thinning@Binarize[Image[ContourPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]},
   {x, range[[1, 1]], range[[1, 2]]},
   {y, range[[2, 1]], range[[2, 2]]},
   Contours -> {0}, PlotPoints -> 30,
   ContourStyle -> White, Background -> Black, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> False]]];
```

After applying `MorphologicalBranchPoints` on this image we find

```
intersPlot = MorphologicalBranchPoints[binPlot];
GraphicsGrid[{{binPlot, Dilation[intersPlot, 1]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then the seeds are just the rescaled positions of 1 in the `ImageData` of `intersPlot`.

```
seeds = DeleteDuplicates[
  Position[Reverse[ImageData[intersPlot]], 2].{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, 
  (ChessboardDistance[#1, #2] <= 1) &];
seeds = Transpose[N@MapThread[
   Rescale[#, {1, #2}, #3] &, 
   {Transpose[seeds], ImageDimensions[intersPlot], range}, 1]];
```

The intersection points can then be found using `FindRoot` as before

```
crossp = {x, y} /. Quiet@FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, 
  {x, #1}, {y, #2}] & @@@ seeds;
DeleteDuplicates[crossp, (Norm[#1 - #2] < .0001 &)]

Show[ContourPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5}, 
    Contours -> {0}, PlotPoints -> 30],
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[crossp]}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 21):

This method is based on the `MeshFunctions`. Detailed description is in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46532/17):

```
Clear[f, g]
f[x_, y_] := -Cos[y] + 2 y Cos[y^2] Cos[2 x];
g[x_, y_] := -Sin[x] + 2 Sin[y^2] Sin[2 x];

Show[{
        ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0},
            {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5},
            ContourStyle -> {Lighter[Brown, .7], GrayLevel[.7]}],
        ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0,
            {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5},
            ContourStyle -> None,
            MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, g[x, y]],
            Mesh -> {{0}},
            MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[4]]
            ]
        }]
```

[image: all cross points in the range]

Note the amplified area, the cross point there is actually out of the specified range. Expanding the x range and using option `PlotPoints -> 300`, we can obtain this point:

```
Show[{
        ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0},
            {x, -7/2, 4.0002}, {y, -9/5, 21/5},
            ContourStyle -> {Lighter[Brown, .7], GrayLevel[.7]}],
        ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0,
            {x, -7/2, 4.0002}, {y, -9/5, 21/5},
            PlotPoints -> 300,
            ContourStyle -> None,
            MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, g[x, y]],
            Mesh -> {{0}},
            MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[4]]
            ]
        }]
```

Comment: This is very nice (+1)! A side-question: what do you use for the zoomed area? Is it within Mathematica or externally?

Comment: @gpap Thanks. It's the crayon style in the Paint in Windows 8 :) But I believe it can be implemented in MMA.

Comment: Couldn't this be even simpler by using `ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0,
  g[x, y] == 0},
 {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5},
 MeshFunctions -> {f[#1, #2] - g[#1, #2] &},
 Mesh -> {{0}},
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]`?

Comment: @JasonB My first `ContourPlot` is for visualization only, which is unnecessary if one just wants to find the crossing. The second `ContourPlot` is for solving the equation. Including only one of `f[x,y]==0` and `g[x,y]==0` as the target in it will notably reduce the computing time.

Answer (score 18):

Here is my revision of Stan Wagon's 3rd Edition function.

It is again faster and IMHO cleaner.

```
FindRoots2D::usage = 
  "FindRoots2D[funcs,{x,a,b},{y,c,d}] finds all nontangential solutions to
   {f=0, g=0} in the given rectangle."; 

Options[FindRoots2D] = {PlotPoints -> Automatic, 
   MaxRecursion -> Automatic};

FindRoots2D[
  funcs : {f1_, f2_}, {x_, a_, b_}, {y_, c_, d_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]
] :=
 Module[{fZero, seeds, fy = Compile[{x, y}, f2]},

  fZero =
    Cases[
      Normal @ ContourPlot[
        f1 == 0,
        {x, a - (b-a)/97, b + (b-a)/103},
        {y, c - (d-c)/98, d + (d-c)/102},
        Evaluate @ FilterRules[{opts}, Options @ ContourPlot] ],
      Line[z_] :> z,
      Infinity
   ];

  seeds = 
    Pick[Rest@#, Rest[#]Most[#]& @ Sign @ Apply[fy, #, 2], -1] & /@ fZero;

  With[{seq = FilterRules[{opts}, Options @ FindRoot]},
    Select[
      Union[
        {x, y} /. FindRoot[funcs, {x, #}, {y, #2}, seq] & @@@ Join @@ seeds,
        SameTest -> (Norm[# - #2] < 1*^-6 &)],
      a <= #[[1]] <= b && c <= #[[2]] <= d &] ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 15):

Here is your own code cleaned up a bit.  It runs about a third faster and most of the time is spent on `ContourPlot`.

```
Options[FindAllCrossings2D] = 
  Sort[Join[Options[FindRoot], {MaxRecursion -> Automatic, 
     PerformanceGoal :> $PerformanceGoal, PlotPoints -> Automatic}]];

FindAllCrossings2D[
 {func1_, func2_},
 {x_, xmin_, xmax_},
 {y_, ymin_, ymax_},
 opts___
] :=
 Module[{contourData, seeds, optsflt, fy = Compile[{x, y}, func2]},

  optsflt[fname_] := Sequence @@
    FilterRules[{opts} ~Join~ Options@FindAllCrossings2D, Options@fname];

  contourData =
    Cases[ Normal @ ContourPlot[
       func1, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, Contours -> {0}, 
       ContourShading -> False, PlotRange -> {Full, Full, Automatic}, 
       Method -> Automatic, Evaluate[optsflt @ ContourPlot] ],
     L_Line :> L[[1]],
     Infinity
    ];

  seeds = 
    Pick[Rest@#, Rest[#]Most[#]& @ Sign @ Apply[fy, #, 2], -1] & /@ contourData;

  Select[
   Union @ With[{seq = optsflt @ FindRoot},
     {x, y} /. FindRoot[{func1 == 0, func2 == 0}, {x, #1}, {y, #2}, seq] &
       @@@ Join @@ seeds],
   (xmin < #[[1]] < xmax && ymin < #[[2]] < ymax) &]

 ]
```

Answer (score 15):

Here's a way that's somewhat more efficient than `FindRoots2D`.  I use `Plot3D` instead of `ContourPlot`, but more importantly for speed, I use `ListPlot` to approximate the zeros of the second function along the first.  These are then polished with `FindRoot` as in other answers.

```
ClearAll[findAllRoots2D];
Options[findAllRoots2D] = Join[Options[FindRoot], Options[Plot3D]];

findAllRoots2D[{f1_, f2_}, {x_, a_, b_}, {y_, c_, d_}, opts___] :=
 Module[{f1plot, f2plot},
  f1plot = Plot3D[f1, {x, a, b}, {y, c, d},
    MeshFunctions -> {Function @@ {{x, y}, f1}},
    Mesh -> {{0}}, PlotStyle -> None,
    PlotRange -> All, BoundaryStyle -> None, Method -> Automatic,
    Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot3D]]];
  f2plot = ListLinePlot[
    Cases[Normal@f1plot, Line[pts_] :> pts[[All, {1, 2}]], Infinity],
    MeshFunctions -> {Function @@ {{x, y}, f2}},
    Mesh -> {{0}}
    ];
  Quiet[Check[
      FindRoot[{f1 == 0, f2 == 0}, {x, #[[1]], a, b}, {y, #[[2]], c, d},
        Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[FindRoot]]], 
      Unevaluated@Sequence[], FindRoot::reged], FindRoot::reged] & /@ 
   Cases[Normal@f2plot, Point[p_] :> p, Infinity]
  ];
```

On the example:

```
f[x_, y_] := -Cos[y] + 2 y Cos[y^2] Cos[2 x];
g[x_, y_] := -Sin[x] + 2 Sin[y^2] Sin[2 x];

pts = {x, y} /. 
    findAllRoots2D[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5}, 
     Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}, 
     PlotPoints -> 85, WorkingPrecision -> 20]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {11.8102, Null}  *)

ContourPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5}, 
 Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> False, 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Red, Point@pts}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`FindRoots2D` takes about 7 seconds longer:

```
FindRoots2D[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5},
     Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}, 
    PlotPoints -> 85, WorkingPrecision -> 20]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {18.6097, Null}  *)
```

[Mr. Wizard's improvement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/770/4999) was 1 sec. faster than `FindRoots2D`.

Comment: It's probably best to stick `Method -> Automatic` somewhere in the options for `f1plot` so that `Method` options for `FindRoot[]` cannot interfere with the plotting in any way. Now that I think about it, the speed may be due to the fact that `Plot3D[]` does a coarser mesh sampling than `ContourPlot[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the suggestion. The mesh lines have 1200 **more** points than the contour lines (for `f1`).  Of course, accuracy also has to do with how the adaptive sampling is carried out.  1200 more points in useless locations don't really help.  But `Plot3D` runs 4-5 sec. faster than `ContourPlot`.

Comment: Really... my experience with `MeshFunctions` is that they often give slightly rougher-looking lines than `ContourPlot[]`'s. Oh well, I guess another one of *Mathematica*'s mysteries.

Comment: @J.M. Maybe it's the `PlotPoints -> 85` in the example.  Perhaps with defaults, `ContourPlot` usually does better.

Answer (score 13):

I am not sure if it is worth pointing out (it might even be mentioned in Stan Wagon’s book  - I have the second edition, but as I am away from home I can’t check it) that these particular system of equations can be solved by *Mathematica* (or, more precisely with the help of *Mathematica*) exactly (by means of `Reduce`) so that all these initial points etc., are quite unnecessary. Here is how you do it:

```
eq1 = TrigExpand[g[x, y]];

eq2 = TrigExpand[f[x, y]] /. Sin[x]^2 -> 1 - Cos[x]^2;

eq = Eliminate[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}, Cos[x]];

solsNonzero = Reduce[Sin[x] != 0 && eq && -5 <= y <= 5, y];

solsZero = Reduce[Sin[x] == 0 && eq && -5 <= y <= 5, y];

sols1 = {x, y} /. 
   N[{ToRules[
      Reduce[solsNonzero && 
        eq1 == 0 && -5 <= x <= 5 && -5 <= y <= 5, {y, x}]]}];

sols2 = {x, y} /. 
   N[{ToRules[
      Reduce[solsZero && f[x, y] == 0 && 
        g[x, y] == 0 && -5 <= x <= 5 && -5 <= y <= 5, {y, x}]]}];

sols = Join[sols1, sols2];

ContourPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> False, 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Red, Point /@ sols}]
```

If you evaluate all the above you should see the already all too familiar picture.

Comment: Sure; I was just looking for a test function for `FindAllCrossings2D[]` and I used Stan Wagon's example. I however use it for more complicated transcendental equations, and the proper analysis is just a liiitle bit out of reach... but thanks for giving the analytical solution.