# RootSearch for complex or multiple equations

Tags: numerics, equation-solving, complex

First the background. I'm trying to solve for the roots of a rather messy complex equation. This is not the exact equation, but it's a decent (simpler) stand in:

```
Tan[x - I a] + I == I (x - I a)^(-1/2)
```

I can use `FindRoot` to solve for a particular root, i.e.

```
FindRoot[Tan[z] + I == (I) (z)^(-1/2), {z, Pi - .3 I}]
```

which gives `{z -> 3.08945 - 0.465902 I}`. The thing is, the real part of these equations (as well as the imaginary parts) alone have periodic solutions. For example, look graphically at this solution:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, realizing that the real roots tend to be spaced roughly at integer factors of $\pi$ (i.e. consider `Tan[x]==x^(-1/2)`), using `FindRoot[Tan[z] + I == (I) (z)^(-1/2), {z, 2 Pi - .3 I}]` indeed gives the next root. However, in the actual equation some roots get spaced un-evenly, and it's possible to miss particular roots when using this guess method.

I recognize that another approach to doing this explicitly solves the real and imaginary parts of the equation as simultaneous roots to two real equations:

```
 FindRoot[{Re[Tan[x + I y] + I] == Re[(I) (x + I y)^(-1/2)], 
   Im[Tan[x + I y] + I] == Im[(I) (x + I y)^(-1/2)]},
  {{x, Pi}, {y, -.3}}]
```

and gives the same result, `{x -> 3.08945, y -> -0.465902}`.

Given this info, is there a way to use a [`RootSearch`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4482/)-type function to find *all* complex (simultaneous) roots to this (these) equation(s) over a particular range of real values **without guessing** each real part of root to be an integer value of $\pi$?

**Edit** As an added complication, I actually have two complex equations that I need to solve simultaneously, so if the solution could be generalizeable to allow for this sort of thing, that would be an added bonus.

---

**Also Edit**
I've tried a few of the suggestions in the comments and answers below. Some work for the sample case I gave above, but for my actual problem they don't really work. So, I figured may as well give the whole crazy thing I'm trying to solve:

```
    s1 = {(-2 ky Pi wavelength Cot[
      1/2 (b ky + n Pi)] + (km - I nm) (4 Pi^2 + 
       ky^2 wavelength^2 - 
       2 ky (km - I nm) Pi wavelength Tan[
         1/2 (b ky + n Pi)]))/((km - I nm) wavelength) == 0, 
          (-2 kx Pi wavelength Cot[
      1/2 (a kx + m Pi)] + (km - I nm) (4 Pi^2 + 
       kx^2 wavelength^2 - 
       2 kx (km - I nm) Pi wavelength Tan[1/2 (a kx + m Pi)]))/((km - I nm) wavelength) == 0}
```

This equation needs to be solved for different values for the parameters in this equation `a`, `b`, `wavelength`, etc. Here's a sample:

```
wavelength = 26 10^-3;
nm = -100;
km = 5;
a = 13 10^-4;
b = 64 10^-5;
m = 1;
n = 0;
```

Now, if I try

```
Solve[{Sequence@@s1, Abs[kx] <= 10, Re[kx] >= 0, Abs[ky] <= 10, Re[ky] >= 0}]
```

I get an error "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.". However, trying `Sequence@@N@s1` it suggests trying exact input.  Similarly, `Reduce` does not work with `N` values, and with exact values takes impossibly long to solve.

So, I'm still looking for a *fast* numerical approach. Perhaps something like J.M. suggested in a comment could be generalized for more than two equations?

Comment: For solving real and imaginary parts simultaneously, maybe [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275) can help...

Comment: @J.M. I think something like that might work for the specific example here, but not the coupled complex equations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Solve` to specify a range of interest.

```
In[10]:= Solve[{Tan[z] + I == (I) (z)^(-1/2), Abs[z]<=10}, z]

(*
Solve::incs: Warning: Solve was unable to prove that the solution set found is
 complete.
*)
```

> ```
> Out[10]= {
>  {z -> Root[{-I + I Sqrt[#1] + Sqrt[#1] Tan[#1] & , 
>
>    -7.132251035054214302104690186362585697068142403087646814465 - 
>
>     0.842662781181162221826225669202853177237728217131893274490 I}]}, 
>
>  {z -> Root[{-I + I Sqrt[#1] + Sqrt[#1] Tan[#1] & , 
>
>    -4.0072460838160107316714173702742991366776869325551029661934 - 
>
>     0.7019645733961268997044074293090492296764597316326821770525 I}]}, 
>
>  {z -> Root[{-I + I Sqrt[#1] + Sqrt[#1] Tan[#1] & , 
>
>    -0.9400640610224741334606974053019750421040015028175053694335 - 
>
>     0.3643340656419651371252025602838905385545008341650161006297 I}]}, 
>
>  {z -> Root[{-I + I Sqrt[#1] + Sqrt[#1] Tan[#1] & , 
>
>    0.42502056063258650274891169514957099586187780514338474096327 + 
>
>     0.28887193948823718272333177173656870529846993666625322445517 I}]}, 
>
>  {z -> Root[{-I + I Sqrt[#1] + Sqrt[#1] Tan[#1] & , 
>
>    3.0894479592377390694689578127850505603723837467810656253546 - 
>
>     0.4659016059311814902662713357028283109716496004755022472595 I}]}, 
>
>  {z -> Root[{-I + I Sqrt[#1] + Sqrt[#1] Tan[#1] & , 
>
>    6.2485902300197850812539412523087220367984004253401247062207 - 
>
>     0.6952369865703343084749992220176303906987008887723814228223 I}]}, 
>
>  {z -> Root[{-I + I Sqrt[#1] + Sqrt[#1] Tan[#1] & , 
>
>    9.3988273465945532374205413428073199349703889446719754737117 - 
>
>     0.8189381870367646618319736159465519157976282115012488727359 I}]}}
> ```

I doubt any roots were missed, warning message notwithstanding. But it can be iffy when dealing with functions that are not everywhere analytic in the region of interest.

Comment: Will this work with 2 coupled complex equations? Also, what would happen if the functions are not everywhere analytic (e.g. discontinuous)?

Comment: I don't know the answer to either. I think it is possible that coupled equations will be amenable. Discontinuities? I'm really not sure.

Comment: Also, consider `Solve[{Tan[z] + I == I (z), Abs[z] <= 2 Pi && Re[z] > 0}, z]`. If I choose `2 Pi` as the maximum range, it finds more roots than if I choose `4 Pi`. See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUv09.png) for an image.

Comment: I am confused by the difference between `Solve` and `Reduce` in v8.  Only `Reduce` works in v7.  Is `Solve` in v8 expanded to include the function of `Reduce` or do they still have distinct purposes?

Comment: I was wondering that myself, actually.

Comment: I'll ask about that Tan[z]+I==I*z example. Might be a bug, might be a limitation of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

A very good algorithm for this is demonstrated [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ComparingIterativeRootFindingMethods/). Details of how `Reduce` finds such roots and what problems it can do are discussed [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/12/18/mathematica-7-johannes-kepler-and-transcendental-roots/).

Comment: Ted, how would those algorithms compare to your fantastic RootSearch function for finding real solutions?

Comment: The algorithm In the demonstration I pointed to will often converge on a complex root even if the initial guess is a real number. The great thing about that method is that it quickly converges for a very wide range of initial guesses. My RootSearch function can only find real roots. If real roots are what you want my function would be better because it will never wonder off the real axis. So each method is very good for different types of problems.