# How to get a solution set of a nonlinear system of equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to find the solution set of `{x, y}` variables for the following system of equations:

```
Solve[{0 == -1/2*Tan[Pi*x/2] + y, 0 == -1/2*Tan[Pi*y/2] + x}, {x, y}]
```

But when I try this, I can't get a result. Is there another function I should use? I can get the "basic" solutions by hand noting that if $x = 0$, then $y = 2n$ where $n$ is an integer (and vice-versa for when $y = 0$). But I think there are other solutions...

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

I'm using Mathematica 8, BTW.

Comment: What you have there is a system of transcendental equations that are difficult to solve in general. If you don't mind approximate solutions, you can use `FindRoot[]` or [`FindAllCrossings2D[]`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275).

Comment: Or plot the two functions and see where they cross... that will tell you if you should expect to find answers.

Comment: i dont know exactly but, the command `Reduce` may run.

Comment: Can get a result if you restrict the space, e.g. try `Solve[{0 == y - 1/2 Tan[(\[Pi] x)/2], 
  0 == x - 1/2 Tan[(\[Pi] y)/2], -10 <= x <= 10, -10 <= y <= 10}, {x, 
  y}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other solutions, this is correct. `ContourPlot` gives an idea:

```
ContourPlot[{
  -.5 Tan[.5 Pi x] + y == 0,
  -.5 Tan[.5 Pi y] + x == 0}, {x, -5.5, 5.5}, {y, -5.5, 5.5},
 PlotPoints -> 20,
 Frame -> False, Axes -> True,
 Exclusions -> Join[
   Table[{x == i}, {i, -5, 5, 2}],
   Table[{y == i}, {i, -5, 5, 2}]]]
```

[image: contourplot]

`Exclusions` prevents drawing of asymptotes and poles. This plot can tell you where to search for roots. (Note also that you don't have to type `*` for multiplication, pressing space instead achieves the same effect.) Now use `FindRoot` for example with starting values you read off the plot (select plot > right click > *Get Coordinates*). Click some points close to intersections and *Ctrl + C* copy them. Let's say these thriteen pasted and assigned to `start`:

```
start = {{-1.279, 1.279}, {0.9913, 2.543}, {3.002, 2.773}, {2.6, 
    0.9913}, {1.336, -1.307}, {-0.4166, -0.589}, {-0.1006, 
    0.1006}, {0.5603, 
    0.5603}, {-2.543, -1.02}, {-0.9913, -2.83}, {-3.031, -2.686}, \
{1.164, -3.405}, {3.175, -1.192}};
Length@start
(* 13 *)
```

I visualize solution points with the same `ContourPlot` command to which I added `Epilog` overdraw specification (black points). You can see that not every starting point (gray) converged to a desired destination. Perhaps I should've start-clicked more carefully, or one could tell `FindRoot` to search differently, you'd have to consult help on that.

```
sol = Map[Function[ini,
   With[{x0 = First@ini, y0 = Last@ini},
    {x, y} /. FindRoot[{
       -.5 Tan[.5 Pi x] + y == 0,
       -.5 Tan[.5 Pi y] + x == 0}, {{x, x0}, {y, y0}}]]], start];
```

[image: contourplot2]

Comment: ...and `FindAllCrossings2D[]` is effectively a mechanical implementation of your approach.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, that's a truly great post and discussion. Should a beginner be pointed to a post like that however, it could scare him s******* easily, no?

Comment: Well, he can just copy the code and turn it loose on his equations... ;)

Comment: Amazing... thank you!