# Constraining solution's sign with NSolve

Tags: equation-solving

I am solving some equations in 4 variables, however, there are many solutions which are basically the same but changing relative signs of each other ... i.e. {x->-1,y->1} and {x->1,y->-1}.
Nevertheless I am only interested in solutions with positive values for x and negative values for y. Is there anyway to implement this in NSolve?
I was trying to add an additional equation

```
NSolve[eq1==a&&eq2==b ... &&y<0,{x,y}]
```

However, this is not working. Is it the wrong way tom implement it?

Comment: Solve everything and then `Select` desired solutions?

Comment: At this stage that wouldn't be a problem, however later conditions may get more involved and I was wondering whether there would be an automated way to do it ...

Comment: can you show more of your actual code? For me e.g. this is working: `NSolve[(x + y)^2 + (x - y)^2 == 1 && (x + y)^4 + (x - y)^4 == 1 && 
  x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}]` gives only the positive solution wheras `NSolve[(x + y)^2 + (x - y)^2 == 1 && (x + y)^4 + (x - y)^4 == 1, {x, y}]` gives all four solutions.

Comment: Sorry, the equations are rather long to copy it here and with greek letters, superscript, etc.. so it woudl be a nightmare to copy. Then I guess for some reason, for this equation, implementing this kind of condition takes Mathematica a long time, so I will go with Select in the end I guess
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @pablo You may switch to `FindRoot`. How would you specify `x > 0` then?

Comment: @BoLe I was not using `FindRoot`, and looking in the documentation I haven't found such a possibility ...
Thanks for your answer below!

Comment: @pablo With `FindRoot` you must provide starting values, seeds. You may want to automate that. See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25459/how-to-get-a-solution-set-of-a-nonlinear-system-of-equations) which also links to such function `FindAllCrossings2D[]` in particular.

Comment: @BoLe Ok, I see, that may be useful too, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
solution = With[{n = 10, r := RandomReal[{-1, 1}]},
  Table[{x -> r, y -> r, z -> r, w -> r}, {n}]];

Select[solution, 
 With[{u = Apply[ArcTan, {x, y} /. #]}, -.5 Pi < u < 0] &]
```

Or:

```
Cases[solution, {x -> a_ /; a > 0, y -> b_ /; b < 0, __}]
```

Comment: This will do the job :)
Thanks a lot!