# Find all roots in the interval of nonlinear equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am struggling on how to find all the roots of `1+1/2^x+1/3^x==0` which lie in a given of real and imaginary interval.

`Solve` does not work, and `FindRoot` only returns one root.
Is there a better way to get as many roots as possible?
Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

If you restrict the domain where to look for roots, `Reduce` can often find them and will return `Root` objects which can be used in exact symbolic calculations.  Even better, [it guarantees to give you *all* roots in that domain](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/12/18/mathematica-7-johannes-kepler-and-transcendental-roots/).

```
Reduce[1 + 1/2^x + 1/3^x == 0 && Abs[x] < 5, x]
(* x == Root[{1 + 3^#1 + E^(-(Log[2] - Log[3]) #1) &, 0.4543970081950240272783427420109442288880772534469111379406 - 3.5981714939947587422049363529208471165604257466288393398421 I}] || 
   x == Root[{1 + 3^#1 + E^(-(Log[2] - Log[3]) #1) &, 0.4543970081950240272783427420110 + 3.5981714939947587422049363529208 I}] *)
```

When looking for real roots, the typical way to restrict the domain is something similar to `0 < x < 1`.  We're looking for complex roots her so I used `Abs[x] < 5`.

Related:

- [About multi-root search in Mathematica for transcendental equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5663/12)
- [Updating Wagon's FindAllCrossings2D[] function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/275/12)

---

To use the `FindRoots2D` function from the linked post, you need to break the equation into real and imaginary parts, as follows:

```
f[z_] := 1 + 1/2^z + 1/3^z

FindRoots2D[{Re@f[x + I y], Im@f[x + I y]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]

(* {{0.454397, -3.59817}, {0.454397, 3.59817}} *)
```

Comment: I am trying your code. But it runs so long that I have not seen the result yet while I am replying to you. How long did u take to run this code? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you give me some basic instructions to use Wagon's FindAllCrossing2D[] function?

Comment: @user16023 It takes less than a second in both v8 and v9.  `FindAllCrossings2D` finds the roots of a system of two equations on the reals (not complexes).  You can break your equation into real and imaginary parts then follow the instructions from the post I linked.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need approximate numerical solution rather than the exact solution (i.e., [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) object) you could use [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) also with a constrained domain for x.

```
eqn = 1 + 1/2^x + 1/3^x == 0;

soln = NSolve[{eqn, Abs[x] <= 5}, x, WorkingPrecision -> 10]

(*  {{x -> 0.454397008 + 3.598171494 I}, {x -> 0.454397008 - 3.598171494 I}}  *)

And @@ (eqn /. soln)

(*  True  *)
```