# Faster variant of Reduce for finding zeros of holomorphic functions in a region

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

I'm currently using `Reduce` to find zeros of a function in a region on a complex plane:

```
Reduce[q[s]==0 && 0 < Re[s] < 1 && 0 < Im[s] < 50]
```

`q[s]` is a large Dirichlet polynomial:

```
q[s_] := Sum[a[n]/n^s, {n, 1, 70}]
```

(the sum in my case is explicit with explicit coefficients, but it does not matter here, I believe)

This function is entire, and so I expected Mathematica to find its zeros rather quickly - as far as I know, there exist special algorithms for finding zeros of a holomorphic function in a region. However, `Reduce` is very slow - on my machine it could easily take 2-3 hours or even more to locate zeros of one polynomial.

Does Mathematica have some special built-in algorithm for this? For example, Maple has `RootFinding[Analytic]` function which does indeed find zeros of my functions relatively quickly (usually in less than a minute or two), but it fails for unknown reason when the degree of a polynomial is above 60-70 and when the region is larger than approximately 1x50 (and anyway I prefer using Mathematica for my computations). Numeric approximation of roots is perfectly acceptable for me, absolute accuracy is unnecessary - however, if I use `NSolve` it works even slower :( Maybe there is a way to tweak the performance of `Reduce` somehow? I couldn't find any relevant options in its documentation.

I believe it is possible to run `FindRoot` over some grid of points in the region but I don't want to do it because it is easy to miss some zeros this way.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/netvl/3b0a80421a990aa21290) is an example of the Dirichlet polynomials I'm working with.

Comment: Is the variable `s`? If so, this seems like it might be difficult since it's not polynomial.

Comment: Yes, the variable is `s`. I searched the internet and found some papers which suggest methods of numerical approximations of zeros of holomorphic functions - and it seems that one of them is used in Maple. I wonder if Mathematica also has something like it, maybe in form of parameters to generic functions like with `NIntegrate` and its methods of integration.

Comment: I think numeric integration is sometimes used by `Reduce` although I am not absolutely certain it is used in this example. That of course does not address the speed issue under consideration. One thing I will suggest is that you post an explicit example (no symbolic `a[n]`, that is). That way readers might have something to test against.

Comment: For a numerical solution, you could try one of the answers to [Updating Wagon's FindAllCrossings2D function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/275/245), using the real and imaginary parts of your function as input.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, thanks, I should have done it since the beginning but all this time Mathematica was computing the next portion of zeros and I didn't want to interrupt it. I've added a link to an example function.

Comment: @Jens, yes, I saw that some time ago and unless I find something more appropriate I think I will go that way. Still hoping for something less "hacky".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out that `Reduce` finds candidate solutions relatively quickly and spends the vast majority of time proving correctness and completeness of the result. `NSolve` didn't have its own code for handling such problems, and was ending up using the same code as Reduce, finding symbolic solutions, and then numericizing them. I have implemented an `NSolve` version of the code, which only verifies candidate solutions numerically. It will be a part of the next *Mathematica* release. Unfortunately, I don't see an easy way of making the current *Mathematica* skip the symbolic solution verification... You can try the following code which directly calls the internal function finding candidate solutions.

```
nsol[f_, {x_, a_, b_}] :=
   Module[{pf, cand, rts},
      pf=Evaluate[f/.x->#]&;
      Reduce`AnalyticRootIsolation;
      cand=System`TRootsDump`GuessRoots[pf, {a, b}];
      rts=Quiet[x/.(FindRoot[f, {x, #}]&/@cand)];
      rts=Select[rts, 
            Chop[pf[#]]==0 && Re[a]<=Re[#]<=Re[b] && Im[a]<=Im[#]<=Im[b]&]; 
      Union[rts, SameTest->(Chop[#1-#2]==0&)]]

In[3]:= (rts=nsol[f, {s, 0, 1+50 I}]);//Timing
Out[3]= {1.471776, Null}

In[4]:= Length[rts]
Out[4]= 11
```

Comment: Wow, that's very interesting. I did notice that `Reduce` said something about proving correctness. For now I ended up using the approach with analyzing `ContourPlot` as suggested in comments above, but this does answer the question. Looking forward for the next version then :) Thanks!

Comment: Does Mathematica 10.4 implement the process described in your answer?

Comment: ``System`TRootsDump`GuessRoots`` seems now to require a third argument, `True`/`False`, that indicates whether to try harder to find roots.