# Why does the following Solve take so long?

Tags: equation-solving

Why does the following take Mathematica so long to reply to?

```
Solve[BetaRegularized[0.5, k, n - k - 1] == 0.035, k]
```

where $n = 1000$

By the way, In case there is no exact solution, how can I request Mathematica to find the nearest solution?

Comment: I doubt you get an analytic solution. You can try with using `NSolve`.

Comment: For things like this, I think Solve should issue a warning something like: "`Solve` is best at finding symbolic solutions for exact polynomial equations. For this problem, `FindRoot` may be more appropriate if `Solve` cannot find a solution."

Comment: @JohnDoty Yeah, that would get us rid of many questions posted here ;o)

Comment: @JohnDoty Note that `Solve` can handle several kinds of transcendental equations these days.  Look at the docs, under "Scope", both "Complex equations in one variable" and "Real equations in one variable", for examples.

Comment: @Michael E2 sure, `Solve` has heuristics that can attempt to handle a variety of things, but its reliable core is exact symbolic algebra.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look for `FindRoot`. Per default, it tries to use Newton's method. However, the derivatives behave rather badly, so a secant method might be a more robust choice. Brent's method (mixture of bisection and secant method) works very well, here:

```
n = 1000;
b = 0.035;
sol = FindRoot[
  BetaRegularized[0.5, x, n - x - 1] == b, {x, 0.4 n, 0.6 n}, 
  Method -> "Brent"]
F[x] - b /. sol
```

> {x -> 528.115}
>
> -3.84415*10^-15

Note that  `0.4 n` and `0.6 n` are supposed to bracket the root of the equation.

Answer (score 5):

`Solve` originally was principally a solver of polynomial equations $p(x)=0$ and some equations like $p(f(x))=0$ for suitable transcendental functions $f$.  But beginning around V7, I think, efforts have been made to extend the reach of `Solve` so that it might live up to its name.  Many transcendental equations can be solved if the roots can be isolated, and if in no other way, their roots can be represented by exact, symbolic [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects.

It often helps to have exact coefficients.

Here `Solve` works, if the root is isolated and a sufficiently high, but finite, working precision is used:

```
Block[{n = 1000},
 Solve[BetaRegularized[1/2, k, 1000 - k - 1] == 7/200 && 
    2 n/5 <= k <= 3 n/5, k, Reals,
  WorkingPrecision -> 400]
 ]
(*  {{k -> 528.1147041429262349889...}}  *)
```

Alternatively, one can construct the corresponding `Root` object:

```
(sol = Block[{n = 1000},
    With[{f = BetaRegularized[1/2, k, n - k - 1] - 7/200 & /. k -> #},
     Root[{f,
       k /. FindRoot[f[k], {k, n/2, 2 n/5, 3 n/5}, 
         WorkingPrecision -> 400]}]
     ]]) // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {20.7221, 
   Root[{-(7/200) + BetaRegularized[1/2, #1, 999 - #1] &, 
     528.11470414292623498897865816253955484889... + 0.*10^-403 I}]}
*)
```

**Remarks on the numerics of the equation**

We can see that at machine precision, the function is constant for `n = 1000` until the middle of its domain `0 < k < 999`:

```
Block[{n = 1000},
 With[{f = 
    BetaRegularized[0.5, k, n - k - 1] - 0.035 & /. k -> # // 
     Rationalize},
  InputForm /@ Table[f[N@k], {k, 0, 1000, 100}]
  ]]
(*
  {0.965`, 0.965`, 0.965`, 0.965`,
   0.9649999998691152`, 0.4523748657765868`, -0.03499999991364527`,
   -0.035`, -0.035`, -0.035`, -0.035`} 
*)
```

A locally constant function generally stumps solvers that use local methods. One should consider [`RootSearch` or `findAllRoots`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/find-all-roots-of-an-interpolating-function-solution-to-a-differential-equation/16444#16444); or perhaps `` System`TRootsDump`GuessRoots `` (or `` System`TRootsDump`GuessRealRoots ``) from this related Q&A: [Faster variant of Reduce for finding zeros of holomorphic functions in a region](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80383/faster-variant-of-reduce-for-finding-zeros-of-holomorphic-functions-in-a-region/80423#80423)

Perhaps it is not surprising that the derivative is difficult to evaluate at machine precision:

```
Block[{n = 1000},
 With[{f = BetaRegularized[0.5, k, n - k - 1] - 0.035 & /. k -> # // Rationalize},
  Table[f'[N@k], {k, Join[{1}, 100 Range[9], {998}]}]
  ]]
(*
  {-4.46485*10^155, -7.43223*10^246, -8.32217*10^275, 1.77529*10^275, 
   4.69065*10^254, -2.14015*10^216, 3.1861*10^253, -1.13516*10^276, 
   2.6163*10^275, 2.96348*10^246, -4.46485*10^155}
*)
```

You need ~500 digits to get accurate values throughout the whole domain; only ~400 are needed for `k` between `400` and `600`, which perhaps explains why `WorkingPrecision -> 400` works above.

```
Block[{n = 1000},
 With[{f = BetaRegularized[0.5, k, n - k - 1] - 0.035 & /. k -> # // Rationalize},
  N@Table[
    f'[SetPrecision[k, 500]], {k, Join[{1}, 100 Range[9], {998}]}]
  ]]
(*
  {-2.79399*10^-300, -5.31457*10^-162, -7.31643*10^-86, 
   -6.31716*10^-38, -5.41614*10^-11, -0.0252418, -3.60875*10^-11, 
   -2.70387*10^-38, -1.82439*10^-86, -5.86766*10^-163, -2.79399*10^-300} 
*)
```

Comment: Very interesting explanation (+1)

Comment: In my problem, System`TRootsDump`GuessRealRoots works 10 to 300 times slower than Ted Ersek's RootSearch.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is something strange about the derivative of `BetaRegularized`.

First let's plot your function.

```
Show[
 Plot[BetaRegularized[0.5, k, 1000 - k - 1], {k, 450, 550}, 
  PlotStyle -> Black],
 ListLinePlot[{{450, 0.035}, {550, 0.035}}, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I defined a function

```
f[k_] := BetaRegularized[0.5, k, 1000 - k - 1] - 0.035
```

and attempted to locate `k` where `f[k]` was zero.

I tried some numerical methods (e.g, `FindMinimum`, `FindRoot`) and had no luck.

I computed the derivative symbolically and numerically

```
D[f[k], k] /. k -> 520
(* -2.34977*10^206 *)
```

the result is inconsistent with the plot.

I defined an approximate numerical derivative

```
df[k_] := (f[k + 10^-6] - f[k])/10^-6

df[520]
(* -0.0108823 *)
```

This made much more sense.

I then used `FixedPoint` and a simple Newton's method to get an approximation of `k`.

```
FixedPoint[# - f[#]/df[#] &, 530, 20]
(* 528.115 *)
```

Here is a plot on a magnified scale near the solution

```
Show[
 Plot[BetaRegularized[0.5, k, 1000 - k - 1], {k, 527, 529}, 
  PlotStyle -> Black],
 ListLinePlot[{{527, 0.035}, {529, 0.035}}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Graphics[{
   Blue,
   Opacity[0.6],
   PointSize -> 0.025,
   Point[{{528.115, 0.035}}]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So my guess is that there is something strange going on with the derivative.

Note that I am completely unfamiliar with `BetaRegularized` so you may very well get a better answer.

Comment: Very good point. When deriving `BetaRegularized[1/2, k, 1000 - k - 1]` with respect to `k`, we see that fractions of pretty large numbers have to be juggled with, so that there is few hope to compute that accurately with machine numbers.