# A question on using Cases

Tags: core-language

I am working on Wagon's FindRoots2D section.

```
Clear[f];
f[x_, y_] := x - y^2 Cos[y];
g[x_, y_] := -y + x Sin[x];
fcnVec[{x_, y_}] := {f[x, y], g[x, y]};
```

I am starting (still a rookie) to understand that one can get the data of any object in Mathematica. For example, a contour plot.

```
cp = ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

I've learned that if I look at `FullForm[cp]`, I'll see that the data is using the `GraphicsComplex` idea, which I have a beginner's understanding of. If I look at `FullForm[Normal[cp]]`, then I see the `Line` command using the actual data points instead of indices to the `GraphicsComplex` data. Now, Stan Wagon uses the `Cases` command to get those points. I try:

```
Cases[Normal[cp], Line[z_] :> z]
```

And I get an empty set. Then I try Stan's:

```
Cases[Normal[cp], Line[z_] :> z, ∞]
```

And I get all of the points. This is where I am stuck. Why does the Infinity symbol make a difference here?

Comment: BTW, have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/275)?

Comment: The third argument is a *level specification*, as noted in the docs for `Cases[]`. In this case, `∞` is short for "as deep as you can go".

Comment: @J. M. Great link to study. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The explanation is readily found in the documentation of `Cases`.

- `Cases` uses standard level specifications
- The default value for levelspec in `Cases` is `{1}`

The `Line` expressions are not at level 1, and in fact may be at more than one level. Using ∞ as the level spec tells `Cases` to look at all levels.

Comment: Thanks for a nice explanation. Very, very helpful.