# Extract points from ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

I have this ParametricPlot3D

```
sigma = 10;
rho = 27;
beta = 8/3;
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == sigma (y[t] - x[t]), 
    y'[t] == x[t] (rho - z[t]) - y[t], z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - beta z[t],
     x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1, z[0] == 1.05}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 100}, 
   MaxSteps -> 30000];
p = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 100},
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[x]], PlotPoints -> 250]
```

[image]

I would like to extract the data points in the form of a list {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},...} and so I did this

```
data = Cases[p, GraphicsComplex[x__] -> x, {1}][[1]];
```

But the points do not seem to be in the right order, in fact the first number is not my inizial value (0,1,1.05), nor is the last one. If I do

```
Graphics3D@Line@data
```

this is the result

[image]

which is all messed up. How can I extract the points from the plot in the right order?

Comment: Try this: `data = Cases[Normal[p], Line[pts_] :> pts, ∞][[1]]`.

Comment: Wow, that worked, thank you very much! Could you explain your code a little bit, what is Normal doing exactly and why using RuleDelayed instead of the usual rule?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88599)?

Comment: @J.M. Very good, thank you.

Comment: maybe missing the point of the question, but you can ge the points right from the  `NDSolve` result: `Graphics3D@Line[Transpose[Through[{x, y, z}["ValuesOnGrid"]] /. First@sol   ]]`

Comment: @george2079 I didn't know. But isn't some adaptive sampling performed by `Plot`? For example I used `PlotPoints -> 250` but I could have used more. How can I specify that in your code?

Comment: Well, `NDSolve[]` integrates adaptively as well, so for visualization purposes, george's proposal would often suffice. (I actually did that [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23975).)

Comment: @J.M. Good to know, very informative.

Comment: `Plot` can give you fewer points as needed to generate a smooth curve. (Example if you set a small `MaxStepSize` in `NDSolve`, `Plot` will just take the points it needs.).  In this case about the same..  I kind of like having the actual calculated points, not interpolated.

Comment: @george2079 I see, good point. If anybody is curious, in this case using `data2 = Transpose[Through[{x, y, z}["ValuesOnGrid"]] /. First@sol]` I get 12520 points while  `data = Cases[Normal[p], Line[pts_] :> pts, ∞][[1]]` gives me 13110.