# My evaluation is taking a lot of time

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, numerics, complex

I was evaluating the roots of a transcendental equation, when I noticed that *Mathematica* never finishes but stays in the running state. The following is the code that I was using:

```
roots = 
  Reduce[
    Sin[z + Sin[z + Sin[z]]] == Cos[z + Cos[z + Cos[z]]] && 
    -3 < Re[z] < 3 && -3 < Im[z] < 3, 
    z] // Quiet;
```

Comment: As a workaround, you might try using [`FindAllCrossings2D[]`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275) on the real and imaginary components of your function.

Answer (score 5):

`NSolve` with adequate precision works well

```
$Version

(* "10.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)" *)

eqns = Sin[z + Sin[z + Sin[z]]] == Cos[z + Cos[z + Cos[z]]] && -3 < Re[z] < 
    3 && -3 < Im[z] < 3;

roots = NSolve[eqns, z, WorkingPrecision -> 20];

And @@ (eqns /. roots)

(* True *)
```

Note that there are a large number of roots

```
roots // Length

(* 883 *)
```

Comment: It's still not working yet, I did exactly the same as yours, and nothing...

Comment: @WaynerKlën What version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm using Mathematica 9.0 !

Comment: @WaynerKlën In V9, on my Macbook Pro, this answer returns 1305 roots in 151 seconds; my answer returns the 1251 just as in V10 and takes 146 seconds.  (Kinda sad, the regression in V10, even though it's almost 10 times faster.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I really don't know what's happening with my calculations, perhaps my computer, Ireally don't know... Do you think that the source of this problem can be my hardware?

My computer is an Intel I3 - 3,30GHz with 3,40625 GB Ram Memory.

Comment: @WaynerKlën I have a 2.7GHz i7, 16GB.  This computation seems to take about 100MB in both V9/V10.  So it's not obvious what makes the computation slow for you.  You have a small amount of memory, but it meets the minimal specs.  If it affects this computation, it should affect many others, too. I don't know enough to say what advantage the architecture of an i7 would have over an i3 in this problem.  How long did you let it run?

Comment: @MichaelE2 So, I let the mathematica running for approximately one whole night (something about 6 hours)... and nothing... It was still running in the morning... Anyhow, thank you for all support you've given me!

Answer (score 5):

I thought it interesting to ask where the roots determined by Bob Hanlon and Michael E2 lie in the complex plane.

```
pts = Flatten[N[roots, 15] /. Rule[_, z_] -> ReIm[z], 1];
pts2 = Flatten[N[roots2, 15] /. Rule[_, z_] -> ReIm[z], 1];
```

As noted in their answers, the numbers of roots are `883` and `1251`.  One might suppose that the first list is a subset of the second, but that is far from the case.

```
Length[Intersection[pts, pts2]]
Length[Complement[pts, pts2]]
Length[Complement[pts2, pts]]
(* 131
   752
   1120 *)
```

In all, there are `2003` distinct roots, although many lie close together.  In plotting these roots, I noticed that none occurred in the region `-15/10 < Re[z] < 0 && 28/10 < Im[z] < 3` and attempted to find some there

```
eqnsl = Sin[z + Sin[z + Sin[z]]] == Cos[z + Cos[z + Cos[z]]] && 
    -15/10 < Re[z] < 0 && 28/10 < Im[z] < 3;
```

using the methods described in the previous two answers.  `NSolve` produced two more, and `Solve` produced ten more.  All are plotted below.

```
ListPlot[{Complement[pts, pts2], Complement[pts2, pts], Intersection[pts, pts2], 
    Union[ptsl, pts2l]}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green, Red, Brown}]
```

[image]

Many of the points are so close together that they are indistinguishable on the plot.  The twelve roots I found are `Brown`.  (The plot is, or should be, symmetric about the `Re[z]` axis.)  I have high confidence that very many more points could be found with further effort, because the function given in the question oscillates extremely rapidly for larger `Im[z]`.

```
Plot3D[Im[Sin[z + Sin[z + Sin[z]]] - Cos[z + Cos[z + Cos[z]]] /. 
    {z -> x + I y}], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

More `PlotPoints` would show more structure, although the plot soon would become unintelligible.

**Addendum: Roots for z -> - Pi/4 + I y**

One of the forty to fifty sets of roots visible in the first figure lies precisely at `Re[z] -> -Pi/4`, which allows us to take a closer look at it.  The original expression in the question can be rewritten as

```
Nest[Sin[z + #] &, 0, 3] - Nest[Cos[z + #] &, 0, 3]
(* -Cos[z + Cos[z + Cos[z]]] + Sin[z + Sin[z + Sin[z]]] *)
```

Correspondingly, this expression for the set of roots under discussion can be written as

```
s45 = Simplify[Nest[TrigExpand[Sin[-Pi/4 + I y + #]] &, 0, 3] - 
               Nest[TrigExpand[Cos[-Pi/4 + I y + #]] &, 0, 3]]
(* -Sqrt[2] Cosh[y + (Cosh[Sinh[y]/Sqrt[2]] (Cos[Cosh[y]/Sqrt[2]] - Sin[Cosh[y]/Sqrt[2]]) 
   Sinh[y])/Sqrt[2] + (Cosh[y] (Cos[Cosh[y]/Sqrt[2]] - Sin[Cosh[y]/Sqrt[2]]) 
   Sinh[Sinh[y]/Sqrt[2]])/Sqrt[2]] (Cos[(Cosh[y + Sinh[y]/Sqrt[2]] (Cos[Cosh[y]/Sqrt[2]] + 
   Sin[Cosh[y]/Sqrt[2]]))/Sqrt[2]] + Sin[(Cosh[y + Sinh[y]/Sqrt[2]] (Cos[Cosh[y]/Sqrt[2]]
   + Sin[Cosh[y]/Sqrt[2]]))/Sqrt[2]]) *)
```

Conveniently, this expression is purely real, factors, and only the last factor oscillates.

```
Plot[Evaluate[s45[[4]]], {y, 0, 3}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

This oscillatory function can be simplified by

```
s45[[4]] //. Cos[v_] + Sin[v_] :> Sqrt[2] Sin[v + Pi/4]
(* Sqrt[2] Sin[π/4 + Cosh[y + Sinh[y]/Sqrt[2]] Sin[π/4 + Cosh[y]/Sqrt[2]]] *)
```

Consequently, roots are located at integer values of

```
s45ph = %[[2, 1]]/Pi
(* (π/4 + Cosh[y + Sinh[y]/Sqrt[2]] Sin[π/4 + Cosh[y]/Sqrt[2]])/π *)
Plot[s45ph, {y, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Most of the roots evidently are located in the range `{y, 2.7, 3.0}`  A count of the roots can be obtained from the phase function at its first maximum, first minimum, and at y -> 3.

```
NMaximize[{s45ph, 0 < y < 2}, y]
NMinimize[{s45ph, 0 < y < 3}, y]
s45ph /. y -> 3.
(* {2.4042, {y -> 1.59765}}
   {-158.994, {y -> 2.60531}}
   3807.12 *)
```

From these values the number of roots can be estimated as `4129`.  If the other sets have comparable numbers of roots, the total probably is of order `200000`.

Comment: Now that you mention it, the function looks awfully like the start of a fractal…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Yes, it does.  I imagine that there zillions of roots (but not an infinite number).

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.  My earlier estimate of a zillion roots evidently was too large.  A better estimate would appear to be of order `200000`, as noted in the edit to my answer.

Comment: Good analysis. That plot of `s45[[4]]` was frightening, tho. :)

Answer (score 4):

In V10, `Solve` works, too, and gives 1251 solutions.

```
roots2 = Solve[eqns, z]; // AbsoluteTiming
Length@roots2
```

> Solve::incs: Warning: Solve was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete. >>

```
(*
  {99.1951, Null}
  1251
*)
```

Maybe there are more, too.  The timing is almost 6 times as long as [BobHanlon's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9362/bob-hanlon) `NSolve` command on my computer.  But the solutions are exact, so paying some price might be expected.  Here is the first one:

```
First@roots2
(*
  {z -> Root[{Cos[Cos[Cos[#1] + #1] + #1] - Sin[Sin[Sin[#1] + #1] + #1] &, 
             -2.980629752912469515709805878534 - 2.452233595301368860424363570387 I}]}
*)
```

See [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects), if you are unfamiliar with [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html).