# Finding and plotting solutions of a complex function

Tags: plotting

I have a complex function given by

```
f1 = Sqrt[-16 x^4 - 16 y^4 - 16 z^4 - 32 I x^3 \[Pi] + 24 x^2 \[Pi]^2 + 8 I x \[Pi]^3 - \[Pi]^4]
```

When I plot the real part of this function using

```
Plot3D[{Re@f1 /. {z -> 0}, 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

I get
[image]

I see that there are $(x,y)$ at which `Re[f1]==0`. However, when I try to plot these points separately using

```
ContourPlot3D[Re@f1 == 0, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All, ContourStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None,  Boxed -> False]
```

The output is empty!
I have checked [these](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/plotting-implicitly-defined-space-curves) [threads](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99454/plotting-complex-functions-to-find-solutions) and also [these](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29692/contour-plot-of-complex-function-problem-in-choosing-argument) [ones](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269409/plot-various-2d-curves-in-3d) but couldn't figure out why the `ContourPlot3D` does not generate the correct results.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The surface only touchs `z==0`  , Contourplot cannot detect these kind of contours!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe there only several lines which `ContourPlot3D` can not handle.

```
f1 = Sqrt[-16 x^4 - 16 y^4 - 16 z^4 - 32 I x^3 π + 
   24 x^2 π^2 + 8 I x π^3 - π^4]; sol = 
 Reduce[{Re@f1 == 0 /. {z -> 0}, x ∈ Reals, 
   y ∈ Reals}, {x, y}]
reg = Region[Style[ImplicitRegion[sol, {x, y}], Red], PlotRange -> 10,
   Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["x", Bold, Blue, 14], 
    Style["y", Bold, Blue, 14]}]
```

[image]

```
Show[Plot3D[{Re@f1 /. {z -> 0}, 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  MaxRecursion -> 2]
 , Graphics3D[{Red, AbsoluteThickness[5], 
   MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[reg, PlotRange -> 10], 
     1] /. {{x_Real, y_Real} :> {x, y, 0}}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to also plot this result in 3D?

Comment: @Shasa See the updated, It is OK now.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

`ContourPlot` (Mathematica v12.2)  cannot handle contour `z==0` because it's onesided.

```
pic = Plot3D[{Re@f1 /. {z -> 0}, 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3} ,Mesh -> None]
```

`RegionPlot3D` for small region `Re@f1 < .5` might help  to illustrate

```
Show[{pic, RegionPlot3D[Re@f1 < .5, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3},PlotPoints -> 100  , PlotStyle -> Red, Mesh -> None]}]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1)Thanks for your answer and comment.