# How can I improve the accuracy of FindRoot for a complex equation?

Tags: equation-solving, complex, precision-and-accuracy

I want to solve the following problem: Given a complex matrix $m=\textbf{m}(λ, ω)$, with $λ, ω \in \mathbb R$, find $λ$ and $ω$ such that

$$\det[\textbf{m} (λ, ω)] = 0$$

Since one can take the real and imaginary parts of the determinant, we end up with two equations.

I tried to solve it with `FindRoot`. Mathematica seems to find the right solutions for λ and ω, but when I try to plug them in the determinant, the determinant gives back a value of order $10^{-10}$.

I would like the solution to be more accurate so that the determinant would be of order $10^{-12}$ or less, is it possible?

The code is the following:

```
(* Parameters *)
Clear[sp]
ll = 58.3;
xin = 0.0034;
b = 1730;
a = 0.185;
k = 228;
e = 0.1;
t = 0.0038;
l0 = ( b t / xin)^(1/4);
ln[sp_] = sp*l0;
oursp = ll/l0

(* Compute the elements of the 4x4 matrix **m**.  This procedure is very specific to the problem that I’m working with.  *)

(*bc1, bc2, bc4 will be of m*)
bc1[xj_, c_] = (b xj^3 - c a^2 xj);
bc2[xj_] = Exp[xj ln[sp]] xj;
bc4[xj_, c_] = (Exp[xj ln[sp]]) (b xj^2 - c a^2 );

(*To find xj (j=1,2,3,4) we solve a polynomial equation.*)
eigen[c_, s_] = b x^4 - a^2 c x^2 + xin  s;
root = NSolve[eigen[c, s] == 0, x]; 
xx[c_, s_] = x /. root ;

(* Compute the 4x4 matrix and the determinant. *)
m[c_, s_, 
   sp_] = {{bc1[xx[c, s][[1]], c], bc1[xx[c, s][[2]], c], 
    bc1[xx[c, s][[3]], c], bc1[xx[c, s][[4]], c]}, {1, 1, 1, 
    1}, {bc4[xx[c, s][[1]], c], bc4[xx[c, s][[2]], c], 
    bc4[xx[c, s][[3]], c], bc4[xx[c, s][[4]], c]}, {bc2[xx[c, s][[1]]], 
    bc2[xx[c, s][[2]]], bc2[xx[c, s][[3]]], bc2[xx[c, s][[4]]]}};

(* Compute the determinant substituting $c$ and $s$ with explicit expressions.
   The expression for $c$ will depend on $s$ and `lambda`. The parameter`s = I omega` is purely imaginary *)

det[lambda_, omega_, sp_] = Det[m[k + I omega e - (lambda  I omega)/(1 + I omega t),I omega, sp]];

(* Compute the solution *)
solc = FindRoot[{Re[det[lambda, omega, oursp]] == 0, 
   Im[det[lambda, omega, oursp]] == 0}, {lambda, 
   7.2}, {omega, 290}]
(*out: {lambda -> 7.22856, omega -> 285.74}*)
```

The problem of accuracy:

```
{lambdac,omegac} = {lambda,omega}/.solc;
det[lambdac, omegac, oursp]
(*out: -4.36557*10^-10 + 4.07454*10^-10 I*)
```

P.S. The scope of this computation is to find the non-trivial solutions **A**=(A1,A2,A3,A4)^T, of **m**(λc, ωc)**A**=**0**

P.P.S. I've tried to read the answer to [Improve Accuracy of FindRoot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107603/improve-accuracy-of-findroot), but I fear it is too complicated for my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this particular case, you can use [exact numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18485#18485) instead of inexact by applying [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) to all your parameters. Then, use `Solve` instead of `NSolve`. Finally, increase [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) of FindRoot.

```
Clear[sp]
ll = 58.3 // Rationalize;
xin = 0.0034 // Rationalize;
b = 1730;
a = 0.185 // Rationalize;

...

root = Solve[eigen[c, s] == 0, x];

...

solc = FindRoot[{Re[det[lambda, omega, oursp]] == 0, 
   Im[det[lambda, omega, oursp]] == 0}, {lambda, 7.2}, {omega, 290}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 30]

{lambdac, omegac} = {lambda, omega} /. solc;
det[lambdac, omegac, oursp]
(* {lambda -> 7.22856127683466811826154273590, 
    omega -> 285.740490749591546034984866881} *)
(* 0.*10^-22 + 0.*10^-22 I *)
```

Comment: Thanks! It solved the problem :)

Comment: @user123 Note that at machine precision, your original result of `FindRoot` was off from this solution by one or two units in the last place (a relative error from the true root that is less that 4 x 10^-16). It's pretty good and not really needing improvement, if you're going to use machine precision. The residual in this answer, less than 10^-22 starting with 30 digit precision, also shows that the original result, less than 10^-9 starting with 16 digit precision, has similar conditioning near the root and is about as good as can be expected.