# finding the coordinates of intersection point of two complicated implicit function

Tags: equation-solving

I have two complicated functions and i plot the contours of them like this:

```
ContourPlot[{f[x,y]==0,g[x,y]==0},{x,x1,x2},{y,y1,y2}]
```

I would like to find coordinates of intersection points exactly.
I've tried most of solutions people suggested here before line `Nsolve` or `FindRoot` but it does not work and i am forced to get the coordinated by decreasing the domain and recognize the intersection point by eye !!! and use 'get coordinates' option !

I would appreciate if anybody helps me.
Thanks

Comment: It would help if you provide definition of `f[x,y]` and `g[x,y]`. Also your syntax seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275)?

Comment: My functions are some pages if i want to put it here.But i can say that f and g are real and image part of a functions that contains multiples of bessel and hankel functions.

Comment: That's fine; you should still be able to use the functions in the linked thread on those.

Answer (score 3):

### Example

**Code**

```
pts = Solve[y - 2 x^2 + 3/2 == 0 && {x, y} \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, 1],{x,y}];
parabola = ContourPlot[{y - 2 x^2 + 3/2 == 0}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}];
intersections = {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{x, y} /. pts]};

Show[{parabola, Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1], intersections}]}]
```

**Output**

[image: example]

**Reference**

[Curve Intersection](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/basic-and-formula-regions/curve-intersection.html)

[Show](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html)
[Solve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html?q=Solve)
[ContourPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html?q=ContourPlot)
[Graphics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html?q=Graphics)

Comment: Dear E.Doroskevic
This solution is not suitable for mine.Because if you replace even a simple function like 3 y - 5 x^2 + 7/2 == 0 with Circle[{0, 0}, 1] it does not work. Anyway thank you so much