# FindRoot evaluates the exact same point multiple times. Why?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, mathematical-optimization

This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131808/findroot-using-replacement-rule-inside-body#).

Let's say we want to minimize the following function `f` wrt. `x` and `y`. The approach is to minimize first wrt. to `y` and then wrt. `x`. If this approach makes sense is not part of the question.

```
f[x_, y_] := (x - 2)^2 + x ( y - 2)^2
dx[x_, y_] := Block[{xs}, D[f[xs, y], xs] /. xs -> x]
dy[x_, y_] := Block[{ys}, D[f[x, ys], ys] /. ys -> y]
fy[x_?NumericQ] := y /. FindRoot[dy[x, y] == 0, {y, 20}]
dxnoy[x_] := dx[x, fy[x]]
```

Now using `FindRoot` on `dxnoy` yields the correct result:

```
FindRoot[{dxnoy[x] == 0}, {{x, 5}}]
(* {x -> 2.} *)
```

However, the process seems to be inefficient. Using `EvaluationMonitor` in `FindRoot` reveals that the exact same points `x` are evaluated multiple times:

```
Last[Reap[FindRoot[{dxnoy[x] == 0}, {{x, 5}}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]]]]
(* {{5., 5., 5., 2., 2., 2.}} *)
```

Why is that? Or better: How can it be avoided? It seems to me that the performance could be a factor 3 better if it wouldn't evaluate the points `x=5` and `x=2` three times each.

Comment: Displaying the result with `NumberForm[%, 15]` yields `{{{5.}, {5.}, {5.000000074505806}, {2.}, {2.}, {2.0000000298023224}}}`, so the points `x == 5.` and `x == 2.` actually are computed only twice each.  Still, this is an interesting question.

Comment: Even if the values are not exactly the same it would still be a strange sequence. Normally, the approach to the root is a smooth decay function. Now it is a step function. It seems something is not as it should be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I speculate that the following is occurring.  As I noted in a comment above, the actual values of `x` returned by `EvaluationMonitor` are

```
Last[Reap[FindRoot[{dxnoy[x] == 0}, {{x, 5}}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x}]]]]
NumberForm[%, 25]
(* {{{5.}, {5.}, {5.000000074505806}, {2.}, {2.}, {2.0000000298023224}}} *)
```

To use the `"Newton"` method, `FindRoot` must evaluate both the `dxnoy[x]` and its derivative at each point.  Since `FindRoot` cannot see inside `dxnoy[x]`, it must evaluate the derivative numerically.  This would seem to account for the second evaluation at `x == 5.`, followed by the evaluation at `x ==`5.000000074505806.  It then does the same at `x == 2`.  Convergence is rapid, because `dxnoy[x]` is quadratic.  Evaluation of the derivative numerically at `x == 2.` can be avoided by

```
Last[Reap[FindRoot[{dxnoy[x] == 0}, {{x, 5}}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x}], 
    Method -> {"Newton", "UpdateJacobian" -> 2}]]]
NumberForm[%, 25]
(* {{{5.}, {5.}, {5.000000074505806}, {2.}}} *)
```

The second evaluation at `x == 5.` still seems unnecessary.

Comment: True. I guess specifying the Jacobian would result in eliminating the extra points at `x=5`.

Answer (score 4):

As explained here, the [`Newton's Method`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationNewtonsMethodRoot.html), which is used by default when you have only one starting point, computes Jacobian at every step, which is the most time consuming part. You can tell *Mathematica* to freeze the Jacobian for few steps, thus improving its performance.

```
RepeatedTiming[Last[Reap[FindRoot[{dxnoy[x] == 0}, {{x, 5}}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]]]]]
(* {0.0012, {{5., 5., 5., 2., 2., 2.}}} *)

RepeatedTiming[Last[Reap[FindRoot[{dxnoy[x] == 0}, {{x, 5}}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x], Method -> {"Newton", "UpdateJacobian" -> 2}]]]]
(* {0.00084, {{5., 5., 5., 2.}}} *)
```

This, however, works not really efficient when your guess is close to the actual minimum point.

```
RepeatedTiming[Last[Reap[FindRoot[{dxnoy[x] == 0}, {{x, 2.1}}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]]]]]
(* {0.0014, {{2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2., 2., 2., 2.}}} *)

RepeatedTiming[Last[Reap[FindRoot[{dxnoy[x] == 0}, {{x, 2.1}}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x], Method -> {"Newton", "UpdateJacobian" -> 2}]]]]
(* {0.0012, {{2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2., 2., 2.}}} *)
```

As an alternative, you can force `FindRoot` to use the [`Secant`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationSecantMethod.html) method instead (which is the default for two starting points). However, the evaluation will fail, as `FindRoot` can't work with an identity equation, which is what `dy[x, y] == 0` becomes when x is evaluated at 0 (which is what Secant method will try to do). In order to fix it, we need to modify the `fy`:

```
xi=0.1;
fy[x_?NumericQ] := If[dya[x, _] =!= 0, y /. FindRoot[dya[x, y] == 0, {y, 20}], y /. FindRoot[dya[x + xi, y] == 0, {y, 20}]]

RepeatedTiming[Last[Reap[FindRoot[{dxnoya[x] == 0}, {{x, 2.1}}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x], Method -> {"Secant"}]]]]
(* {0.00087, {{2.1, 0., 2.1, 2.}}} *)
```

You might need to try several methods depending on your function and the initial guess.

Answer (score 2):

In this sort of problem in which $y=h(x)$ is defined implicitly by $g(x,y)=0$, we can compute its derivative $h'(x)$ in terms of $g(x,h(x))$:

```
fy /: fy' = (fy'[#] /. First@Solve[D[dy[#, fy[#]] == 0, #], fy'[#]] //
      Evaluate) &;
```

Here $h$ is `fy` and $g$ is `dy`. Now `FindRoot` can calculate the derivative (`Jacobian`) of `dxnoy`.

```
ClearAll[f, fy, dx, dy, dxnoy];
f[x_, y_] := (x - 2)^2 + x (y - 2)^2;
dx[x_, y_] := Block[{xs}, D[f[xs, y], xs] /. xs -> x];
dy[x_, y_] := Block[{ys}, D[f[x, ys], ys] /. ys -> y];
mem : fy[x_?NumericQ] := mem = y /. FindRoot[dy[x, y] == 0, {y, 20}];
fy /: fy' = (fy'[#] /. First@Solve[D[dy[#, fy[#]] == 0, #], fy'[#]] //
      Evaluate) &;
dxnoy[x_] := dx[x, fy[x]];

Last[Reap[
  FindRoot[{dxnoy[x] == 0}, {{x, 5}}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]]]]
(*  {{5., 2.}}  *)
```

You may notice I memoized (cached) values of `fy`. That's because `dxnoy'[x]` evaluates `fy[x]`.

```
(*
  dxnoy'[x]
  2 + (2 (2 - fy[x]) (-2 + fy[x]))/x  
*)
```

So what you gain in fewer functions evaluations of `dxnoy[x]` by `FindRoot`, you would lose in the evaluate of `dxnoy'[x]` if the values of `fy[x]` were not saved.  Since `fy[x]` calls `FindRoot`, it is a comparatively expensive function to evaluate and probably worth memoizing.  Local memoization may be obtained with `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{fy},
 Last[Reap[
   FindRoot[{dxnoy[x] == 0}, {{x, 5}}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]]]]
 ]
```

The saved definitions will be deleted and the memory freed once excution leaves the `InheritedBlock`.