# Find all pairs $(x,y)$ for which two functions are equal within a given range

Tags: equation-solving, functions

Suppose I have two functions $p(x,y)$ and $q(x,y)$. I would like to check if there is any pair $(x,y)$ within a range $(0,0)$ to $(\hat{x},\hat{y})$ for which $p(x,y)=q(x,y)$. And if such pair exists, I would like to print them. Is it possible to do with Mathematica?

Update:
As per the link provided by "bbgodfrey", I tried the following input:

```
f[x_, y_] := -Cos[y] + 2 y Cos[y^2] Cos[2 x];

g[x_, y_] := -Sin[x] + 2Sin[y^2] Sin[2 x]; 

pts = FindCrossings2D[{f, g}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y,-9/5, 21/5}]
```

And got the following output:

> FindCrossings2D[{f, g}, {x, -(7/2), 4}, {y, -(9/5), 21/5}]

I wish I could get the list of all crossings as $(x,y)$ coordinates within the specified range.

Comment: It certainly is possible, and a few earlier questions have addressed this issue.  Basically, you are searching for the zeroes of `p[x, y] - q[x, y]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @ bbgodfrey, Thanks, I will remember that.

Comment: Check [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275/updating-wagons-findallcrossings2d-function) for a solution.

Comment: You need to define the `FindAllCrossings2D` function, it is not a built in MMA function. It's definition (in terms of other built in MMA functions) is given in the first grey cell of the answer linked to by bbgodfrey; copy that code, evaluate it, then your above code should work.

Comment: Also be sure to obey the syntax required by `FindAllCrossings2D`. Spell its name correctly, `FindAllCrossings2D`, not `FindCrossings2D`, and it needs `{f[x,y], g[x,y]}`, not just `{f,g}` in its argument list. (Side note, undefined functions (and variables) will appear blue in your notebook, once defined they will turn black).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating Wagon's FindAllCrossings2D\[\] function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275/updating-wagons-findallcrossings2d-function)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can visualize the crossings:

```
f[x_, y_] := -Cos[y] + 2 y Cos[y^2] Cos[2 x];
g[x_, y_] := -Sin[x] + 2 Sin[y^2] Sin[2 x];
Plot3D[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5}, 
 MeshFunctions -> (f[#1, #2] - g[#1, #2] &), Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
 PlotRange -> All]
ContourPlot[f[x, y] - g[x, y] == 0, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5}]
```

[image]

In response to comment:

In the following finding zeroes in a range given x (or y):

```
zgivenx[x0_, 
  r_] := {x0, y} /. 
    Quiet@FindRoot[
      f[x0, y] - g[x0, y], {y, #}] & /@ (Range[##, (#2 - #1)/20] & @@ 
    r)
zgiveny[y0_, 
  r_] := {x, y0} /. 
    Quiet@FindRoot[
      f[x, y0] - g[x, y0], {x, #}] & /@ (Range[##, (#2 - #1)/20] & @@ 
    r)
ptsx = zgivenx[1, {-3, 5}]
ptsy = zgiveny[1, {-3, 3}]
ContourPlot[f[x, y] - g[x, y] == 0, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[ptsx], Green, Point[ptsy]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to print all the coordinates $(x,y)$ that satisfies $f(x,y)-g(x,y)==0$ within the given range? And also where I can find literature about what algorithm/numerical method Mathematica is using to solve this problem?

Comment: @usr109876787 see my update. You may need to refine to suit whatever your needs are. I hope, however, this is a useful start. :)

Comment: Indeed it is great to start and thanks a lot!