# Best way to calculate equilibria for a 2d system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I want to add equilibrium points to the or direction field of the autonomous system $dx/dt=f(x,y)$, $dy/dt=g(x,y)$. For simplicity I assume that f and g are smooth functions. How can I use NSolve to obtain just real valued solutions to $f(x,y)=0$, $g(x,y)=0$, where the solutions are constrained to lie in the window $[x_1,x_2]$ x $[y_1,y_2]$? Then I can plot them on my direction field. Reduce didn't do it for me. Also, I want to avoid the use of StreamPlot, even if it has a option to plot equilibria.

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275) might be of interest.

Comment: I'm not sure what I am looking for - a,thou

Comment: "obtain just real valued solutions to $f(x,y)=0$, $g(x,y)=0$, where the solutions are constrained to lie in the window $[x_1,x_2] \times [y_1,y_2]$" in your question can be handled by the routines in the thread I linked to.

Comment: I realize that I have not stated my question properly. What I need to know is how to calculate the number of equilibria without actually knowing their value(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posed, the question is too generic to be answered appropriately. In principle you should be able to use `NSolve` and appropriate constraints, as long as all constants are given appropriate numerical values. Recall that `NSolve` is a *numerical* solver, not a symbolic one.

Consider for instance:

```
With[
 {x1 = -10, x2 = 10, y1 = -3, y2 = 5},
 NSolve[{Sin[x y] == 0, x^2 + y == 0, x1 <= x <= x2, y1 <= y <= y2}, {x, y}, Reals]
]

(*Out: 
{{x -> 0, y -> 0}, {x -> -1.46459, y -> -2.14503}, {x -> 1.46459, y -> -2.14503}}
*)
```