# Finding multiple minimum values

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

If I have this function (just and example)

```
 Plot3D[-Abs[Cos[ y] Sqrt[x] Sqrt[ y] Cos[ x]], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}]
```

I am interested in finding  the locations of the smallest (minimum) 6 values of this function? How can I do that. Apparently, Findminimum and its likes give  me one value.

Thanks for help.

Comment: The absolute value is troublesome. Is your actual function like this, where the function values are all nonpositive?

Comment: Replacing `Abs` by `Function[x,x^2]` leads to a smooth function with the same critical points.

Comment: @qahtah Are you aware that you can accept answers? It's the best way of saying "thanks". See [this help page for more details](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I ask because you've asked six questions on _Mathematica_ SE, but not accepted a single answer. If none of them have been satisfactory, then that's fair enough, but please consider it.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how similar your actual function is to your example, you could try giving [`FindMinimum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimum.html) (see below) or [`FindArgMin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindArgMin.html) a range of reasonable starting values and then just pick the ones you need.

```
f[x_, y_] := -Abs[Cos[y] Sqrt[x] Sqrt[y] Cos[x]]

sol = FindArgMin[{f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[{0, 0}, {20, 20}]}, 
    {{x, #1}, {y, #2}}] & @@@ Tuples[Range[0, 20, π], 2]

Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{#1, #2, f[##]} & @@@ sol]}],
 ViewPoint -> {-1.5, -2, 0}]
```

[image]

Then

```
SortBy[{#1, #2, f[##]} & @@@ sol, Last][[1 ;; 6]]

(* {{18.876, 18.876, -18.8628}, {15.7397, 18.876, -17.222}, {18.876, 15.7397, -17.222}, 
    {15.7397, 15.7397, -15.7239}, {12.606, 18.876, -15.4082}, {18.876, 12.606, -15.4082}} *)
```

gives you the six minimum values and their locations.

Or alternatively:

```
sol = FindMinimum[{f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[{0, 0}, {20, 20}]}, 
    {{x, #1}, {y, #2}}] & @@@ Tuples[Range[0, 20, π], 2];
SortBy[sol, First][[1 ;; 6]]

(* {{-18.8628, {x -> 18.876, y -> 18.876}}, {-17.222, {x -> 18.876, y -> 15.7397}}, 
    {-17.222, {x -> 15.7397, y -> 18.876}}, {-15.7239, {x -> 15.7397, y -> 15.7397}}, 
    {-15.4082, {x -> 12.606, y -> 18.876}}, {-15.4082, {x -> 18.876, y -> 12.606}}} *)
```

and

```
Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{x, y, First@#} /. Last@# & /@ sol]}], 
 ViewPoint -> {-1.5, -2, 0}]
```

gives the same plot. (But I find the `Rule` format can be a little unwieldy.)

Comment: Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematically, it's simple, I think. The function is separable in both axis, so finding the minima along one axis, let say along the $x$-axis, you will have the corresponding ones along the other axis. All the minima in the $xy$-plane will be the combination of both.

Now, along one axis, one function is an monotonic function ($\sqrt{x}$), and the other has the minima, so finding the minima for `-Abs[Cos[x]]` function (except for $x=0$, as $\cos(0)\sqrt{0}=0$) you will have those you are looking for:

```
Reduce[Cos[x]] == 1 || Cos[x] == -1 && x >= 0, x]

(* (C[1] ∈ Integers && x == 2 π C[1]) || (C[1] ∈ Integers && ((C[1] >= 1 && 
   x == -π + 2 π C[1]) || (C[1] >= 0 && x == π + 2 π C[1]))) *)
```

The same for the $y$-axis.

```
Reduce[Cos[y] == 1 || Cos[y] == -1 && y >= 0, y]

(* (C[1] ∈ Integers && y == 2 π C[1]) || (C[1] ∈ Integers && ((C[1] >= 1 && 
   y == -π + 2 π C[1]) || (C[1] >= 0 && y == π + 2 π C[1]))) *)
```

All your minima are all the combinations for `C[1]` and `C[2]` values:

```
data = Flatten[
Table[{π + i*π, π + 
  j  π, -Abs[
   Cos[π + i* π] Sqrt[π + i* π] Sqrt[π + 
      j* π] Cos[ π + j* π]]}, {i, 0, 6}, {j, 0, i}], 1] // N;
Show[{Plot3D[-Abs[Cos[y] Sqrt[x] Sqrt[y] Cos[x]], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 
20}, PlotTheme -> "Classic"], pts}]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

Another idea is to use the `MeshFunctions` option of `ContourPlot[]` (as previously shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46569)) to extract putative positions for the minima, before polishing them with `FindMinimum[]`:

```
(* pretend that the function is a black box *)
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := -Abs[Cos[y] Sqrt[x] Sqrt[y] Cos[x]]

res = Cases[Normal[ContourPlot[Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y] == 0, {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}, 
                               ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
                               MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z},
                                                         Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y]], 
                               PlotPoints -> 55]], 
            Point[{x0_, y0_}] :> (FindMinimum[{f[x, y], 0 <= x <= 20 && 0 <= y <= 20},
                                              {{x, x0}, {y, y0}}]), ∞];

MinimalBy[DeleteDuplicates[res, First[#1] == First[#2] &], First, 6]
   {{-18.8628, {x -> 18.876, y -> 18.876}}, {-17.222, {x -> 18.876, y -> 15.7397}},
    {-15.7239, {x -> 15.7397, y -> 15.7397}}, {-15.4082, {x -> 18.876, y -> 12.606}},
    {-14.0678, {x -> 12.606, y -> 15.7397}}, {-13.352, {x -> 18.876, y -> 9.47749}}}
```

(Replace `FindMinimum[]` with `FindMinValue[]` or `FindArgMin[]` if needed.)