# Wagon's FindAllCrossings2D[] function to find complex roots in a given complex domain

Tags: equation-solving

I am using an modified version of Wagon's FindAllCrossings2D[] function available here [Updating Wagon's FindAllCrossings2D[] function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275/updating-wagons-findallcrossings2d-function). I am defining `f[alpha,w]` and `g[alpha,w]` as the real and imaginary part of function `da[alpha,w]` whose complex roots are to be evaluated.

```
(*Code for Roots Finding*)
(*Options[FindAllCrossings2D] = 
  Sort[Join[
    Options[FindRoot], {MaxRecursion -> Automatic, 
     PerformanceGoal :> $PerformanceGoal, PlotPoints -> Automatic}]];

FindAllCrossings2D[funcs_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, {y_, ymin_, ymax_}, 
  opts___] := 
 Module[{contourData, seeds, tt, 
   fy = Compile[{x, y}, Evaluate[funcs[[2]]]]}, 
  contourData = 
   Map[First, 
    Cases[Normal[
      ContourPlot[funcs[[1]], {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
       Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> False, 
       PlotRange -> {Full, Full, Automatic}, 
       Evaluate[
        Sequence @@ 
         FilterRules[Join[{opts}, Options[FindAllCrossings2D]], 
          DeleteCases[Options[ContourPlot], Method -> _]]]]], _Line, 
     Infinity]];
  seeds = 
   Flatten[Map[#[[
       1 + Flatten[
         Position[Rest[tt = Sign[Apply[fy, #, 2]]] Most[tt], -1]]]] &,
      contourData], 1];
  If[seeds == {}, seeds, 
   Select[Union[
     Map[{x, y} /. 
        FindRoot[{funcs[[1]] == 0, 
          funcs[[2]] == 0}, {x, #[[1]]}, {y, #[[2]]}, 
         Evaluate[
          Sequence @@ 
           FilterRules[Join[{opts}, Options[FindAllCrossings2D]], 
            Options[FindRoot]]]] &, 
      seeds]], (xmin < #[[1]] < xmax && ymin < #[[2]] < ymax) &]]]*)

(*Program For Sliding Control*)
Clear[sigma, sigmab, xib, cn, ct, a, l, ei, tau, pb, fb, fc, ks, aa,bb, k, lamda, xi, b, lp, w, alpha, da, an]
cn = 0.0034;
ct = 0.0017;
a = (0.185*10^(-6))/2;
l = 58.3*10^(-6);
ei = 1700*10^(-24) // N;
tau = 0.004;
pb = 0.03;
fb = 3.8*10^(-12) // N;
fc = 2*10^(-12) // N;
fp = 1.8*10^(-6) // N;
ks = 94.8*10^(-3) // N;
gama = 0.273*10^(-3) // N;
rho = 150*10^(6) // N;
k3 = 800*10^(12) // N;
aa = 2*rho*pb*(1 - pb)*fb*fp/fc;
bb = 2*rho*pb*fp;
k = -1620;
lamda = -7.60;
sigma[alpha_, w_] := alpha + I*w;
xi[alpha_, 
   w_] := (-aa*(alpha + I*w)/(1 + (alpha + I*w)*tau)) + (bb*(alpha + 
       I*w));
sigmab[alpha_, w_] := (alpha + I*w)*cn*l^4/ei ;
xib[alpha_, 
   w_] := ((-aa*(alpha + I*w)/(1 + (alpha + I*w)*tau)) + (bb*(alpha + 
         I*w)))*a^2*l^2/ei;
lp[alpha_, 
   w_] := ((-aa*(alpha + I*w)/(1 + (alpha + I*w)*tau)) + (bb*(alpha + 
         I*w)))*a^2*l^2/ei;
nomodes = 1;
(*Calculation of Elements of Matrix*)
b = {1.875, 4.694, 7.8548, 10.9955, 14.1372, 17.2788, 20.4204, 
   23.5619, 26.7035, 29.8451, 32.9867, 36.1283, 39.2699, 42.4115, 
   45.5531, 48.6947};
an = (-Sin[b] + Sinh[b])/(Cos[b] + Cosh[b]);
q = an*(Cos[b*x] - Cosh[b*x]) + (Sin[b*x] + Sinh[b*x]);
qx = D[q, x];
qxx = D[qx, x];
qxxx = D[qxx, x];
phi = an*(-Cos[b*x] - Cosh[b*x]) + (-Sin[b*x] + Sinh[b*x]);
phix = D[phi, x];
phixx = D[phix, x];
phixxx = D[phixx, x];
cm = Table[
   NIntegrate[phi[[i]]*q[[j]], {x, 0, 1}], {i, nomodes}, {j, nomodes}];
coeffMat[alpha_, w_] := Table[
  k1m = NIntegrate[phixx[[i]]*qxx[[j]], {x, 0, 1}];
  k2m = NIntegrate[phix[[i]]*qx[[j]], {x, 0, 1}];
  k3ma = phi[[i]]*qxxx[[j]] + phi[[i]]*lp[alpha, w]*qx[[j]] - 
     phix[[i]]*qxx[[j]] /. x -> 1;
  k3mb = phi[[i]]*qxxx[[j]] + phi[[i]]*lp[alpha, w]*qx[[j]] - 
     phix[[i]]*qxx[[j]] /. x -> 0;
  k3m = k3ma - k3mb;
  km = k1m + lp[alpha, w]*k2m + k3m, {i, nomodes}, {j, nomodes}]
da[alpha_, w_] = Det[coeffMat[alpha, w] + sigmab[alpha, w]*cm]
f[alpha_, w_] = Re[da[alpha, w]]
g[alpha_, w_] = Im[da[alpha, w]]
pts = FindAllCrossings2D[{f[alpha, w], g[alpha, w]}, {alpha, -100, 
    100}, {w, -400, 400}, 
   Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}, 
   PlotPoints -> 85, WorkingPrecision -> 20] // Chop
ContourPlot[{f[alpha, w], g[alpha, w]}, {alpha, -100, 100}, {w, -400, 
  400}, Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> False, 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Red, Point /@ pts}]
```

There are certain problems which I am facing

- While calculating matrix form of `coeffMat[alpha,w]` using `Table` function its showing error `$Failed`
- When using the `FindAllCrossings2D[]` it is unable to find the roots

  **(I think the first error is leading to the failure in finding the
  roots because of improper definition of the
  functions`coeffMat[alpha,w]`)**

Please help me out!

Thanks in advance

Comment: That sure is a lot of code you're asking people to work through...

Comment: I don't know if that's where the problem comes from, but `f[alpha, w]` cannot evaluate `Im[w]` or `Re[alpha]` (and others) because it did not specify that `w` and `alpha` are `Reals`. Compare your `f[alpha, w]` with `FullSimplify[ComplexExpand@Re[f[alpha, w]], alpha > 0 && w > 0]` for example.

Comment: Before using a sophisticated function, I recommend starting to plot the curves you want to find the intersections. This helps detect implementation problems and understand the mathematical problem.