# Intersection between an exponential function and a polynomial function

Tags: equation-solving, intersection

I am trying to see if the two graphs intersect each other or not. If they intersect, I want to know the points too. One is an exponential function in and the other is a polynomial function in two variables $x$ and $y$. I was using `Solve` to do the same before when both were polynomial functions. Now, `Solve` just returns the arguments.

```
Solve[4 + 0.2 Exp[-x] == (-0.38 x^2 - 
    x (0.05 (0.2 - 1.6 y) + 0.2 (-2.9 - 0.2 y)) - 
    0.8 y (0.15 - 0.2 y + 0.9 (-3 + 2 y)))/(0.2 x + 0.8 y) && x >= 0 &&
   y >= 0, {x, y}]
```

Can you please guide me with this?

Comment: Using subscripts is not a very good idea; why not just use `x` and `y`? Also, you are now solving a transcendental equation, and `Solve[]` is not very good at those. If you are plotting them anyway, have a look at `MeshFunctions`.

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive, thank you for the advice. I have renamed the variables. I will also look at `MeshFunctions`

Comment: The example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46569) might be of use.

Comment: See if you can make use of `Solve[4 + 
   0.2 Exp[-x] == (-0.38 x^2 - 
     x (0.05 (0.2 - 1.6 y) + 0.2 (-2.9 - 0.2 y)) - 
     0.8 y (0.15 - 0.2 y + 0.9 (-3 + 2 y)))/(0.2 x + 0.8 y), {y}]`

Comment: Yes, `Solve[]` is a bit cleaner here.  `NSolve[]` replaces `e^m` with `2.71828^m`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Contourplot more directly to show the solutionrange  of `f1[x]==f2[x,y]`

```
ContourPlot[f1[x] == f2[x, y] , {x, -c, c}, {y, -c, c} , FrameLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

This contour equals the solution of `NSolve[f1[x] == f2[x, y] , {x, y}]`

Comment: Yes, very nice!  This clearly shows where the solution is!  The place of discontinuity is where the denominator equals zero:  `p = ContourPlot[f1[x] == f2[x, y], {x, -c, c}, {y, -c, c}, 
   FrameLabel -> {x, y}]; q = ContourPlot[.2 x + .8 y == 0, {x, -c, c}, {y, -c, c}, 
   ContourStyle -> Red]; Show[p, q]`

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no solution when both $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge0$.

Here are some quick plots:

```
 c = 3;
 f1[x_] = 4 + Exp[-x];
 f2[x_, y_] = (-0.38 x^2 - x (0.05 (0.2 - 1.6 y) + 0.2 (-2.9 - 0.2 y)) 
               - 0.8 y (0.15 - 0.2 y + 0.9 (-3 + 2 y)))/(0.2 x + 0.8 y);
 ContourPlot[{f2[x, y]}, {x, 0, c}, {y, 0, c}, 
   Contours -> 10, FrameLabel -> {x, y}]
 Plot[f1[x], {x, 0, c}, AxesLabel -> {x, 4 + Exp[-x]}]
```

[image]

At the innermost contour shown, $f_2(x,y) = 2$ and the value of $f_2(x,y)$ along the other contours decreases as $x$ and $y$ increase.  The function $f_1(x,y)=4+\exp(-x)$ is bounded between $4$ and $5$ for $x\ge0$.

Also,

```
 f2[10^-30, 10^-30]
```

returns

2.61.

If you relax the conditions $\{x\ge0,y\ge0\}$, *Mathematica* will return solutions:

```
 NSolve[4. + 0.2 Exp[-x] == (-0.38 x^2 
        -x (0.05 (0.2 - 1.6 y) + 0.2 (-2.9 - 0.2 y)) 
        -0.8 y (0.15 - 0.2 y + 0.9 (-3 + 2 y)))/(0.2 x + 0.8 y), 
        {x, y}]
```

does give a complicated expression for $y$ as a function of $x$.