# Finding and visualization of branch cuts and branch points

Tags: plotting, functions, complex, visualization

Is it possible to determine branch cuts and branch points for complicated functions using mathematica

Iam trying to determine the brnach cuts and branch points of this complicated function

We have 8 branch cuts 
[image]

And I calculated the branchPoints in exact and numeric form

And I have tried to visualize the branchPoints and branchcuts but I had a problem
[image]
$$\sqrt{(\tanh(z) -\tanh(2z))^2 +(\tanh(z)*\tanh(2z)+1)^2-1-2\tanh(z)^2 \tanh(2z)^2}$$

And I calculate
I have tried in mathematica but it's not obvious for me where are the branch cuts ?

```
ContourPlot[Im[Sqrt[(Tanh[x + I*y] - Tanh[2 x + I*2 y])^2 + (Tanh[x + I*y] 
         Tanh[2 x + I*2 y] + 1)^2-1 - 2 ((Tanh[x + I*2 y])^2)((Tanh[x + I*y])^2) ]],
           {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, AxesLabel -> Automatic,ContourShading -> Automatic, 
                         ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",  Contours -> 20]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[Re[Sqrt[(Tanh[x + I*y] - Tanh[2 x + I*2 y])^2 + (Tanh[x + I*y]Tanh[2 x + I*2 y] + 1)^2 - 1 - 2 ((Tanh[x + I*2 y])^2) ((Tanh[x + I*y])^2) ]],
                     {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, AxesLabel -> Automatic,
ContourShading -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",  Contours -> 20]
```

[image]

How Can I visualize the banchPoints and the branchCuts ?

Comment: The first step might be to find all the zeros of the function under the square root. Perhaps [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/275/12558) might help.

Comment: Please can you put the equation in a form that can be copied to a mathematica notebook? (Edit your post please.) This is helpful  for those of us who might try out approaches.

Comment: Ok, Thank you . I have just edited my post .

Comment: I think I should find the zeros of the Imaginary part of the function under the square root , and finding when is the real part is non negative if I am talking about the principal branch excluding the negative real axis . I have tried to find all the zeros of the function under the square root using mathematica but the output was not clear to me

Comment: You have one instance of `x + I*2 y` in your formula. Do you mean for that to be `2x + I*2 y`?

Comment: Yes , I mean $2x+I*2y$

Comment: There was a super smart guy at MATHEMATICA [Trott] who wrote the Mathematica Guidebooks - he wrote one for programming and it deals with branch cuts and the inconsistencies brilliantly. I hope this of help. All the Guidebooks are all out of print and relate to MATHEMATICA 5 but some commands are obsolete but there
are work arounds for MATHEMATICA 12. There are guidebooks covering numerics and graphics and they are huge in scope and in
a way only equalled by books by WELLIN. I am interested in XAI and MATHEMATICA is the gift that keeps on
giving and I am running it on a RASPBERRY PI 4.
Regards-

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this case, the only branch cuts and branch points will come from the square root. The cuts of $\sqrt{f(z)}$ occurs along the half line $\text{Im}(f(z)) = 0 \,\wedge\, \text{Re}(f(z)) \leq 0$. The branch points lie at $f(z) = 0$ or $f(z) = \tilde\infty$.

Your example:

```
With[{z = x + I y},
  expr = (Tanh[z] - Tanh[2 z])^2 + (Tanh[z] Tanh[2 z] + 1)^2 - 1 - 2 ((Tanh[2 z])^2) ((Tanh[z])^2);
  branchCutRegion[x_, y_, __] = Re[expr] <= 0;
];

bpvals = Union[{x, y} /. Solve[(expr == 0 || 1/Together[TrigToExp[expr]] == 0) && -10 < x < 10 && -10 < y < 10, {x, y}]];
```

Here we needed to help `Solve` find the branch points corresponding to $\tilde\infty$.

We can visualize the cut by plotting the constraint on the imaginary part, restricted to the region defined by the constraint on the real part. Here I've overlaid the branch points:

```
ContourPlot[Im[expr] == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  RegionFunction -> branchCutRegion, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  Epilog -> {Red, Point[bpvals]}
]
```

[image]

---

For fun we can add a plot of the expression under the cuts. Here I'll use [domain coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring). Here, the complex argument varies with hue and the absolute value varies with saturation and brightness -- the darker the pixel, the larger the absolute value. I've also binned the absolute value to show some contours.

```
binnedabs = Compile[{{z, _Complex}},
  Module[{f, abs, rnd, sgn, val},
    f = (Tanh[z] - Tanh[2 z])^2 + (Tanh[z] Tanh[2 z] + 1)^2 - 1 - 2 Tanh[2 z]^2 Tanh[z]^2;
    abs = Abs[f];
    rnd = Round[abs, .2];
    val = If[rnd == 0, f, rnd Sign[f]];
    {
      Divide[Mod[Arg[val], 2π], 2π], 
      Power[1 + 0.3*Log[Abs[val] + 1], -1], 
      Power[1 + 0.5*Log[Abs[val] + 1], -1]
    }
  ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  Parallelization -> True,
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
];

lattice = Array[List, {2048, 2048}, {{-10., 10.}, {-10., 10.}}].{I, 1};

raster = Raster[binnedabs[lattice], {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, ColorFunction -> Hue];

cutplot = ContourPlot[Im[expr] == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  RegionFunction -> branchCutRegion, PlotPoints -> 100, ContourStyle -> Black];

Show[
  cutplot, 
  ImageSize -> 800,
  Prolog -> raster, 
  Epilog -> {EdgeForm[Black], GrayLevel[.8], Disk[#, Scaled[.0045]] & /@ bpvals}
]
```

[image]

---

As of version 12 we can use [`ComplexPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexPlot.html) to visualize the domain coloring:

```
exprz = (Tanh[z] - Tanh[2 z])^2 + (Tanh[z] Tanh[2 z] + 1)^2 - 1 - 2 ((Tanh[2 z])^2) ((Tanh[z])^2);
exprxy = exprz /. z -> x + I y;
branchCutRegion[x_, y_, __] = Re[exprxy] <= 0;

bpvals = Union[{x, y} /. Solve[(expr == 0 || 1/Together[TrigToExp[expr]] == 0) && -10 < x < 10 && -10 < y < 10, {x, y}]];

domaincoloring = ComplexPlot[exprz, {z, -10 - 10 I, 10 + 10 I}, 
  ColorFunction -> "CyclicLogAbsArg", ImageSize -> 800];

cutplot = ContourPlot[Im[exprxy] == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  RegionFunction -> branchCutRegion, PlotPoints -> 100, ContourStyle -> Black];

Show[
  domaincoloring,
  cutplot,
  Epilog -> {EdgeForm[Black], GrayLevel[.8], Disk[#, Scaled[.0045]] & /@ bpvals}
]
```

[image]

To achieve the same image from my original answer, you can use

```
domaincoloring = ComplexPlot[exprz, {z, -10 - 10 I, 10 + 10 I}, 
  ColorFunction -> {Hue[Divide[Mod[#8, 2π], 2π], 
    Power[1 + 0.3*Log[#7 + 1], -1], 
    Power[1 + 0.5*Log[#7 + 1], -1]] &, None}, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  Exclusions -> None, 
  ImageSize -> 800
];
```

Comment: In accordance with https://www.dropbox.com/s/zh7mq932rlvb1uk/branch_cuts.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Thank you very much .

Comment: How to get the output domain coloring as you have got ?

Comment: I have a problem running your second code for domain cloring ,I didn't get the output as you got , Would you please check your second code again ?

Comment: In your first code , the lines in blue are the branchcuts right ? I am tring to visulalize the boolean expression and conditional expression for the 8 branchcuts acording to my results

Comment: @topspin It works fine for me in version 11.3. Here's a screengrab showing the copy pasted code from this post: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S3qb.png.

Comment: @topspin Yes, the blue lines are the branch cuts of your expression. In the domain coloring, I colored them black.

Comment: @topspin note that V12 makes the domain coloring easier to achieve. See my edit.

Comment: Ok ,Thank you . Now I am still downloading Mathematica version 11.3 to try to get the output as you have got .but, Is Mathematica version 12 released ? Do you have mathematica version 12 ?

Comment: Right now it’s only released on the cloud and so it’s probably going to release any day now.

Answer (score 18):

Perhaps you can make use of the internal functions `` ComplexAnalysis`BranchCuts `` and `` ComplexAnalysis`BranchPoints ``. First, use a complex variable `z` instead of `x + I y`:

```
expr = Sqrt[(Tanh[z]-Tanh[2z])^2+(Tanh[z] Tanh[2z]+1)^2-1-2 Tanh[z]^2Tanh[2z]^2];
```

Then, for example, the branch points are:

```
pts = ComplexAnalysis`BranchPoints[expr, z]
```

> {ConditionalExpression[-(I/(2 π C[1])), C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[2 I π C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[1/(-((I π)/4) + 2 I π C[1]), 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[-((I π)/4) + 2 I π C[1], 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[1/((I π)/4 + 2 I π C[1]), 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[(I π)/4 + 2 I π C[1], 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[1/(-((I π)/2) + 2 I π C[1]), 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[-((I π)/2) + 2 I π C[1], 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[1/((I π)/2 + 2 I π C[1]), 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[(I π)/2 + 2 I π C[1], 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[1/(-((3 I π)/4) + 2 I π C[1]), 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[-((3 I π)/4) + 2 I π C[1], 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[1/((3 I π)/4 + 2 I π C[1]), 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[(3 I π)/4 + 2 I π C[1], 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[1/(I π + 2 I π C[1]), 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[I π + 2 I π C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[1/(
>     2 I π C[1] + Log[(-(1/2) + I/2) - Sqrt[-1 - I/2]]), 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[2 I π C[1] + Log[(-(1/2) + I/2) - Sqrt[-1 - I/2]], 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[1/(2 I π C[1] + Log[(1/2 - I/2) - Sqrt[-1 - I/2]]),
>      C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[2 I π C[1] + Log[(1/2 - I/2) - Sqrt[-1 - I/2]], 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[1/(
>     2 I π C[1] + Log[(-(1/2) + I/2) + Sqrt[-1 - I/2]]), 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[2 I π C[1] + Log[(-(1/2) + I/2) + Sqrt[-1 - I/2]], 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[1/(2 I π C[1] + Log[(1/2 - I/2) + Sqrt[-1 - I/2]]),
>      C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[2 I π C[1] + Log[(1/2 - I/2) + Sqrt[-1 - I/2]], 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[1/(
>     2 I π C[1] + Log[(-(1/2) - I/2) - Sqrt[-1 + I/2]]), 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[2 I π C[1] + Log[(-(1/2) - I/2) - Sqrt[-1 + I/2]], 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[1/(2 I π C[1] + Log[(1/2 + I/2) - Sqrt[-1 + I/2]]),
>      C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[2 I π C[1] + Log[(1/2 + I/2) - Sqrt[-1 + I/2]], 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[1/(
>     2 I π C[1] + Log[(-(1/2) - I/2) + Sqrt[-1 + I/2]]), 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[2 I π C[1] + Log[(-(1/2) - I/2) + Sqrt[-1 + I/2]], 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[1/(2 I π C[1] + Log[(1/2 + I/2) + Sqrt[-1 + I/2]]),
>      C[1] ∈ Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[2 I π C[1] + Log[(1/2 + I/2) + Sqrt[-1 + I/2]], 
>     C[1] ∈ Integers]}

The above can be simplified a bit with:

```
Simplify[pts, C[1] ∈ Integers]
```

> {-(I/(2 π C[1])), 2 I π C[1], (4 I)/(π - 8 π C[1]), 
>    1/4 I π (-1 + 8 C[1]), -((4 I)/(π + 8 π C[1])), 
>    1/4 I (π + 8 π C[1]), (2 I)/(π - 4 π C[1]), 
>    1/2 I π (-1 + 4 C[1]), -((2 I)/(π + 4 π C[1])), 
>    1/2 I (π + 4 π C[1]), (4 I)/(3 π - 8 π C[1]), 
>    1/4 I π (-3 + 8 C[1]), -((4 I)/(3 π + 8 π C[1])), 
>    1/4 I π (3 + 8 C[1]), -(I/(π + 2 π C[1])), 
>    I (π + 2 π C[1]), 1/(
>    2 I π C[1] + Log[(-(1/2) + I/2) - Sqrt[-1 - I/2]]), 
>    2 I π C[1] + Log[(-(1/2) + I/2) - Sqrt[-1 - I/2]], 1/(
>    2 I π C[1] + Log[(1/2 - I/2) - Sqrt[-1 - I/2]]), 
>    2 I π C[1] + Log[(1/2 - I/2) - Sqrt[-1 - I/2]], 1/(
>    2 I π C[1] + Log[(-(1/2) + I/2) + Sqrt[-1 - I/2]]), 
>    2 I π C[1] + Log[(-(1/2) + I/2) + Sqrt[-1 - I/2]], 1/(
>    2 I π C[1] + Log[(1/2 - I/2) + Sqrt[-1 - I/2]]), 
>    2 I π C[1] + Log[(1/2 - I/2) + Sqrt[-1 - I/2]], 1/(
>    2 I π C[1] + Log[(-(1/2) - I/2) - Sqrt[-1 + I/2]]), 
>    2 I π C[1] + Log[(-(1/2) - I/2) - Sqrt[-1 + I/2]], 1/(
>    2 I π C[1] + Log[(1/2 + I/2) - Sqrt[-1 + I/2]]), 
>    2 I π C[1] + Log[(1/2 + I/2) - Sqrt[-1 + I/2]], 1/(
>    2 I π C[1] + Log[(-(1/2) - I/2) + Sqrt[-1 + I/2]]), 
>    2 I π C[1] + Log[(-(1/2) - I/2) + Sqrt[-1 + I/2]], 1/(
>    2 I π C[1] + Log[(1/2 + I/2) + Sqrt[-1 + I/2]]), 
>    2 I π C[1] + Log[(1/2 + I/2) + Sqrt[-1 + I/2]]}

Similarly, the branch cuts can be found with:

```
ComplexAnalysis`BranchCuts[expr, z]
```

> C[1] ∈ 
>     Integers && ((1/2 Log[Root[1 - 2 #1 - 2 #1^2 - 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 1]] < 
>         Re[z] < 0 && (Im[
>            z] == -ArcTan[Sqrt[(3 + 4 E^(2 Re[z]) + 3 E^(4 Re[z]))/(
>              1 + E^(4 Re[z]))]] + π C[1] || 
>          Im[z] == ArcTan[Sqrt[(3 + 4 E^(2 Re[z]) + 3 E^(4 Re[z]))/(
>             1 + E^(4 Re[z]))]] + π C[1])) || (Re[z] == 
>         0 && (1/2 (-π + 2 π C[1]) < Im[z] < 
>           1/4 (-π + 4 π C[1]) || 
>          1/4 (-π + 4 π C[1]) < Im[z] < π C[1] || π C[1] < 
>           Im[z] < 1/4 (π + 4 π C[1]) || 
>          1/4 (π + 4 π C[1]) < Im[z] < 
>           1/2 (π + 2 π C[1]))) || (0 < Re[z] < 
>         1/2 Log[Root[1 - 2 #1 - 2 #1^2 - 2 #1^3 + #1^4 &, 2]] && (Im[
>            z] == -ArcTan[Sqrt[(3 + 4 E^(2 Re[z]) + 3 E^(4 Re[z]))/(
>              1 + E^(4 Re[z]))]] + π C[1] || 
>          Im[z] == ArcTan[Sqrt[(3 + 4 E^(2 Re[z]) + 3 E^(4 Re[z]))/(
>             1 + E^(4 Re[z]))]] + π C[1])))

Comment: Thank you very much .

Comment: Is there any way to visualize those branch points and the branch cuts in Mathematica Instead of ContourPlot ?

Comment: Or visualizing the branch points and the branch cuts using ContourPlot .

Comment: Just to compare: the Maple's result https://www.dropbox.com/s/zh7mq932rlvb1uk/branch_cuts.pdf?dl=0 seems to be different.

Answer (score 6):

First start with the branch points:  these are the values of z where the root is not multiple-valued. 
First:

```
myexp = Together[
  TrigToExp[
   FullSimplify[(Tanh[z] - Tanh[2 z])^2 + (Tanh[z] Tanh[2 z] + 1)^2 - 
     1 - 2 Tanh[z]^2 Tanh[2 z]^2]
   ]]
```

$$\frac{\left(e^{2 z}-1\right)^2 \left(4 e^{2 z}+10 e^{4 z}+4 e^{6 z}+e^{8 z}+1\right)}{\left(e^{2 z}+1\right)^2 \left(e^{4 z}+1\right)^2}$$

Now solve for the zeros of the denominator and numerator.  I'll do the numerator:  First obtain a polynomial in e^z and then solve the polynomial in terms of a polynomial in just z:

```
  Expand[Numerator[
      Together[TrigToExp[
        FullSimplify[(Tanh[z] - Tanh[2 z])^2 + (Tanh[z] Tanh[2 z] + 
             1)^2 - 1 - 2 Tanh[z]^2 Tanh[2 z]^2]
        ]]]]
    mySol = z /. 
       Solve[1 + 2 z^2 + 3 z^4 - 12 z^6 + 3 z^8 + 2 z^10 + z^12 == 0, z];
```

Now make the substitution Log[z] and keep in mind Log[z]=Log[Abs[z]]+i (Arg(z)+2k pi) so that we have a set of branch points for all integer k.  I will do k=0,1,-1 and then plot the results:[image]

```
p1 = Show[
   Graphics[{Red, 
     Point @@ {{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ (N[Log[#]] & /@ mySol)}}], 
   Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 5];
p2 = Show[
   Graphics[{Blue, 
     Point @@ {{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ (N[(Log[#] + 2 \[Pi] I)] & /@ 
          mySol)}}], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 15];
p3 = Show[
   Graphics[{Green // Darker, 
     Point @@ {{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ (N[(Log[#] - 2 \[Pi] I)] & /@ 
          mySol)}}], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 15];
Show[{p1, p2, p3}, PlotRange -> 15]
```

Comment: Thank you very much .