# I have a potential but I can not obtained the equilibrium points from this potential. How can I plot the basin of attraction at equilibrium points

Tags: plotting

My potential is the form as:

$$
 U =  0.515755 (x^2 + y^2) - 1.0156333 x(0.0200/((-0.1 + x)^2 + y^2)^{(3/2)} + 0.006750/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^{(7/2)} - 0.0180000/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^{(5/2)} - 3.6/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^{(3/2)} - 0.3600000/(((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2) \sqrt{0.0001 + (x^2 + y^2)^2})) + 1.0156333 (x^2 + y^2) (0.2/((-0.1 + x)^2 + y^2)^{(3/2)} - 0.0075/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^{(7/2)} + 0.02/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^{(5/2)} + 4/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^{(3/2)} +  0.4`/(((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2) \sqrt{0.0001 + (x^2 + y^2)^2}))
$$

In Mathematica code:

```
U[x_, y_]:= 
  0.515755 (x^2 + y^2) - 1.0156333 x (0.0200/((-0.1 + x)^2 + y^2)^( 3/2) + 
   0.006750/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^(7/2) - 0.0180000/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^(5/2) - 
   3.6/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^(3/2) - 0.3600000/(((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)*Sqrt[0.0001 + (x^2 + y^2)^2])) +
   1.0156333*(x^2 + y^2)*(0.2/((-0.1 + x)^2 + y^2)^(3/2) - 0.0075/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^(7/2) +
   0.02/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^( 5/2) + 4/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^(3/2) +
   0.4/(((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)*Sqrt[0.0001` + (x^2 + y^2)^2])
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3):

your Mathematica code has some syntax error I corrected it. This is what I have done:

**1)** eqn

```
 U[x_, y_] :=  0.515755 (x^2 + y^2) - 1.0156333 x (0.0200/((-0.1 + x)^2 + y^2)^(3/2) + 
 0.006750/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^(7/2) - 
 0.0180000/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^(5/2) - 
 3.6/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^(3/2) - 
 0.3600000/(((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)*Sqrt[0.0001 + (x^2 + y^2)^2])) + +1.0156333*(x^2 + y^2) (0.2/((-0.1 + x)^2 + y^2)^(3/2) - 
 0.0075/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^(7/2) + 
 0.02/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^(5/2) + 4/((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)^(3/2) + 
 0.4/(((0.9 + x)^2 + y^2)*Sqrt[0.0001` + (x^2 + y^2)^2]));
```

**2)** Take partial Derivatives to find functions to minimize

```
   funs = D[U[x, y], #] & /@ {x, y};
```

**3)** Generally, you equate these to zero and solve it for variables but for a complex equation often we resort to numerical methods. You can use
[FindAllCrossings2D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275/updating-wagons-findallcrossings2d-function) for this purpose but you need to know ranges of x and y's:

```
   pts = FindAllCrossings2D[funs, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Method -> 
        {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"},  PlotPoints -> 85]//Chop
```

Just do a [ListPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) of these to find the plot of x and y values.