# How to solve this coupled integral equation, Mathematica returns the expression without evaluation

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, special-functions

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
l = 1;
ψ[n_, x_] := 
  Exp[-x^2/(2 l^2)] HermiteH[n, x/l]/Sqrt[2^n Factorial[n] Sqrt[Pi] l];
ee[ξ_, x_, Δ0_, Δ1_] := 
  Sqrt[ξ^2 + 
    0.25 l (ψ[0, x] Δ0 + ψ[2, 
          x] Δ1)^2];
kk[j1_?NumericQ, 
  j2_?NumericQ, ξ_?NumericQ, Δ0_?
   NumericQ, Δ1_?NumericQ] := 
 0.125 NIntegrate[ψ[2 j1, x] ψ[2 j2, x]/
     ee[ξ, x, Δ0, Δ1], {x, -20, 20}]
ξ = 0.1;
NSolve[{kk[0, 
      0, ξ, Δ0, Δ1] Δ0 +
     kk[0, 1, ξ, Δ0, Δ1] \
Δ1 == Δ0, 
  kk[1, 0, ξ, Δ0, Δ1] \
Δ0 + 
    kk[1, 1, ξ, Δ0, Δ1] \
Δ1 == Δ1}, {Δ0, \
Δ1}]
```

I have checked the above code, I found no problem. It seems Mathematica has not tried to solve it, just return the same expression.

I have tried to solve a simpler equation with only one variable (also have numerical integral), `NSolve` can handle.

Comment: You might be better off pursuing an approach similar to the one [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/275) instead; looking at the result of `With[{ξ = 0.1}, ContourPlot[{kk[0, 0, ξ, Δ0, Δ1] Δ0 + kk[0, 1, ξ, Δ0, Δ1] Δ1 == Δ0, kk[1, 0, ξ, Δ0, Δ1] Δ0 + kk[1, 1, ξ, Δ0, Δ1] Δ1 == Δ1}, {Δ0, -1/2, 1/2}, {Δ1, -1/2, 1/2}]]` seems to indicate that all the roots you are interested in are in the domain shown.

Comment: related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259542/72111

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ContourPlot` shows the solution:

```
eqn={kk[0,0, \[Xi], \[CapitalDelta]0, \[CapitalDelta]1] \[CapitalDelta]0 +kk[0, 1, \[Xi], \[CapitalDelta]0, \[CapitalDelta]1] \\[CapitalDelta]1 == \[CapitalDelta]0, kk[1, 0, \[Xi], \[CapitalDelta]0, \[CapitalDelta]1] \\[CapitalDelta]0 + kk[1, 1, \[Xi], \[CapitalDelta]0, \[CapitalDelta]1] \\[CapitalDelta]1 == \[CapitalDelta]1} 

pic=ContourPlot[, {\[CapitalDelta]0, -.5, .5}, {\\[CapitalDelta]1, -.5, .5}];
```

solutions:

```
pi=Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[pic  ];
Show[{pic,Graphics[{Red,Point[pi]}]}]
```

[image]

altenative

The intersection points might be found with `NMinimize` instead of `NSolve`:

```
J = # . # &[eqn /. Equal -> Subtract]
```

For example the two positive solutions:

```
NMinimize[{J, \[CapitalDelta]0 > \[CapitalDelta]1 >0}, {\[CapitalDelta]0, \[CapitalDelta]1}]   
(*{3.13997*10^-21, {\[CapitalDelta]0 -> 0.273414, \[CapitalDelta]1 -> 0.157877}}*)
NMinimize[{J, \[CapitalDelta]1 > \[CapitalDelta]0 >0}, {\[CapitalDelta]0, \[CapitalDelta]1}]
(*{5.69988*10^-18, {\[CapitalDelta]0 -> 0.126083, \[CapitalDelta]1 -> 0.250507}}*)    /
```

Comment: What is the magic symbol ` mean, it seems `FindIntersection` function is not documented.

Comment: Look in the documentation for `ResourceFunction`