# Using Mesh in ContourPlot to find intersections not working

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, mesh

[This old answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46569/6358) by @Silvia uses `Mesh` to find intersections of curves.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work in v13.2.  For example (based on @JasonB's comment to that answer):

```
Clear[f, g]
f[x_, y_] := -Cos[y] + 2 y Cos[y^2] Cos[2 x];
g[x_, y_] := -Sin[x] + 2 Sin[y^2] Sin[2 x];

ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5},
  MeshFunctions -> {f[#1, #2] - g[#1, #2] &}, Mesh -> {{0}},
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]
```

[image]

There should be red points at the intersections.  Any thoughts on how to get this working?  What changed?

Comment: I also test v11.3 (work),v12.3( not work) , Something must be changed in v12.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can use two `MeshFunctions`  `{f[#1, #2] &, f[#1, #2] - g[#1, #2] &}`

```
ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 
  21/5}, MeshFunctions -> {f[#1, #2] &, f[#1, #2] - g[#1, #2] &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I wonder what changed.

Comment: Even a dummy first function like `MeshFunctions -> {0 #1 &, f[#1, #2] - g[#1, #2] &}` seems to work.

Comment: @ChrisK It is also curious to me that `{0 &, f[#1, #2] - g[#1, #2] &}` also work.