# A simpler or more concise way to divide the boundary of a polygon into equal arc lengths?

Tags: graphics, geometry, code-request, code-review, polygons

I am really looking just for the least amount of code needed to do this but it is still readable.

Here is the same polygon but the border is respectively split up into 10, 20, and 30 points along the perimeter:

[image: Polygon with boundary split up into 10 equal parts.]
[image: Polygon with boundary split up into 20 equal parts.]
[image: Polygon with boundary split up into 30 equal parts.]

The code I used to produce this is:

```
OrderVerticesClockwise[pts_List] := Module[
  {pivot, sorted, remainingPoints},
  
  (* Find the pivot: the lowest and leftmost point *)
  pivot = First[SortBy[pts, {Last, First}]];
  
  (* Remove the pivot from the list *)
  remainingPoints = DeleteCases[pts, pivot];
  
  (* Sort the remaining vertices based on the polar angle relative to the pivot *)
  sorted = SortBy[remainingPoints, ArcTan[#[[1]] - pivot[[1]], #[[2]] - pivot[[2]]] &];
  
  (* Return ordered vertices with the pivot at the beginning *)
  Prepend[sorted, pivot]
]

Clear[EquidistantPoints];

EquidistantPoints[pts_List, n_Integer] := Module[
  {
    closedPts = Append[pts, First[pts]],
    lengths, totalLength, interval, accumulatedLengths, currentPt, nextPt,
    distRemaining, currentIndex, result = {}
  },
  
  lengths = EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[closedPts, 2, 1];
  totalLength = Total[lengths];
  interval = totalLength/n;
  
  accumulatedLengths = Accumulate[lengths];
  
  Do[
    distRemaining = i*interval;
    currentIndex = 1;
    
    While[distRemaining > accumulatedLengths[[currentIndex]],
      currentIndex++;
    ];
    
    distRemaining -= If[currentIndex > 1, accumulatedLengths[[currentIndex - 1]], 0];
    
    currentPt = closedPts[[currentIndex]];
    nextPt = closedPts[[currentIndex + 1]];
    
    AppendTo[result, currentPt + (distRemaining/lengths[[currentIndex]]) * (nextPt - currentPt)];
    
    , {i, 0, n - 1}
  ];
  
  result
]

equiArcLengthPointQuantity=20;
poly = RandomPolygon[12];
vertices = PolygonCoordinates[poly];
orderedVertices = OrderVerticesClockwise[vertices];
equiArcDistances = Accumulate[Table[Perimeter[poly]/equiArcLengthPointQuantity, {i, 1, equiArcLengthPointQuantity}]];
equidistantPts = EquidistantPoints[orderedVertices, equiArcLengthPointQuantity];

Graphics[
  {Polygon[orderedVertices], Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[equidistantPts]}
]
```

I would assume that there is a much simpler way of doing this, but I couldn't think of one. And I don't know what else to call these points. They aren't equally distanced points in Euclidean space, just along the perimeter by arc length.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}` partly work.

```
poly = RandomPolygon[10];
plot=ListLinePlot[Append[#, First@#] &@poly[[1]], 
 MeshFunctions -> {0 &, "ArcLength"}, Mesh -> {Subdivide@10}, 
 MeshStyle -> Red, Epilog -> {Opacity[.2], poly}, Axes -> False]
```

```
pts =Cases[plot // Normal, Point[p_] :> p, -1] // DeleteDuplicates
```

[image]

Comment: Where did you find "ArcLength" for MeshFunctions? `MeshFunctions -> {0 &, "ArcLength"`

Comment: @DanielHuber  The setting `0&` come from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/277682/72111 The MeshFunctions of `"ArcLength"` is well know in this forum.

Comment: ArcLength seems not always to give equidistant points. E.g.:  `Plot[Sin[x ], {x, 0, 10}, MeshFunctions -> {0 &, ArcLength}, 
 Mesh -> {10}, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.03]}]` Do you know where to find info anout this?

Comment: @DanielHuber  `Mesh -> {10}` will ignore the boundary points. So we need to use `Mesh->{Subdivide@10}` etc.

Comment: The points are still not equidistant. Where did you find info about "ArcLength"?

Comment: @DanielHuber  This points are equidistant.  For example, `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, π*3}, MeshFunctions -> {0 &, "ArcLength"}, 
 Mesh -> {{0, 0.5, 1}}, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.03]}]` or `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, π*3}, MeshFunctions -> {0 &, "ArcLength"}, 
 Mesh -> {Subdivide[0, 1, 6]}, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.03]}]`

Comment: You are right, I integrated it. It only looks optical different.

Comment: @cvgmt pts is always empty when I run it.

Comment: @TegLouis  Updated for old version, for example v12.3.1( I am using v13.3.1)

Comment: @cvgmt It completely works now. I use Google Chromebook, so I have to use the wolframcloud.com version.

Answer (score 4):

We first create the points of a random polygon:

```
m = 10 ; (* polygon *)
pts = CirclePoints[m];
pts = RandomReal[{0.1, 2}] # & /@ pts;
AppendTo[pts, pts[[1]]];
```

Then we calculate the lines and their lengths of the border:

```
border = Partition[pts, 2, 1];
dist = Total[Norm[Subtract @@ #] & /@ border]/n;
```

Finally we distribute the points along the perimeter:

```
n = 12;(* number of points *)
rest = 0;
pts1 = Reap[Sow[pts[[1]]];
    Scan[(tmp = #[[1]];
       While[rest + Norm[#[[2]] - tmp] >= dist,
        Sow[
         tmp = tmp + (dist - rest)/Norm[#[[2]] - tmp] (#[[2]] - tmp)];
         rest = 0;];
       rest = Norm[#[[2]] - tmp]) &, border]
    ][[2, 1]];
Graphics[{Line[pts], Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[pts1]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My primary tool is `Interpolation`:

```
 With[{poly = RandomPolygon[10], n = 50},
  With[{len = ArcLength@RegionBoundary@poly},
   (* Get a sequence of line segments. *)
   Partition[MeshPrimitives[poly, 2][[1, 1]] // Append[#, First@#] &, 
      2, 1, 1] //
     (* Create a linear constant-speed interpolation
        through polygon vertices. *)
     Interpolation[
       Transpose[
        {Accumulate[
          Prepend[EuclideanDistance @@@ Most@#, 0]], #[[All, 1]]}],
       InterpolationOrder -> 1] & //
    (* Generate points at constant intervals. *)
    Table[#[t], {t, 0, ((n - 1)/n) len, len/n}] &] // 
  Graphics[{poly, Red, PointSize@Large, Point@#}] &]
```

[image]

With `poly = N@RegularPolygon[{1, 0}, 1000], n = 12`:

[image]

By replacing two last lines of code with this you get an animation:

```
Animate[Graphics[{poly, Red, PointSize@Large, Point@#[t]}], {t, 0, len}] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"];

LSC[pts_, divs_] := Map[LineScaledCoordinate[pts, N @ #] &] @ Subdivide[divs]
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1];

poly = RandomPolygon[10];

Graphics[{ Red , AbsolutePointSize[7], 
  Point[LSC[Append[#, First @ #] & @ poly[[1]], 10]], 
  EdgeForm[Gray], Opacity[.1], poly}]
```

[image]

Replace `LSC[Append[#, First @ #] & @ poly[[1]], 10]` with `LSC[Append[#, First @ #] & @ poly[[1]], 5]` to get

[image]

```
Plot[x Sin[3 x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> {LightRed, LightBlue},
 DisplayFunction -> 
  (Show[#, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize @ Large, 
     Point[First @ Cases[Normal@#, Line[x_] :> LSC[x, 7], All]]}] &)]
```

[image]