# Poorly behaved ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, numerics

I am interested in finding the interested in finding the intersections of the curves `f1==0,f2==0` and `g==0` (defined below). My initial idea (which has served me well in the past) was to an implementation of Wagon's `FindAllCrossings2D[]` (discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275/updating-wagons-findallcrossings2d-function)).

However, before I embarked on that enterprise, I decided to play around with `ContourPlot` to see what my functions look like. I have included a code snippet below. My primary issue is the visualizations produced by `ContourPlot` aren't particularly well behaved. I have included some screenshots to demonstrate this.

First for `d=0` case shown below, the contours look somewhat reasonably except for the the jagged lines for small `c`. I have played around with `MaxRecursion` and setting `Exclusions -> True` to remedy this but to no avail.

Is there someway to fix this behavior for `ContourPlot`? Alternatively, is there some other method to a) find the zero level contours for these functions and (b) determine their intersection points?

**Update** Resolved thanks to user @demm incrasing `PlotPoints` solves this issue.

```
lmb[c_, ea_, ep_, d_, l_] := (z - 2)*Exp[ea]*Exp[-c (ep + d^2/2 )]

p[c_, ea_, ep_, d_, l_] := 
 1 - (Sqrt[(4*c*lmb[c, ea, ep, d, l])/l + 1] - 1)/((
  2*c*lmb[c, ea, ep, d, l])/l)

func[c_, ea_, ep_, d_, l_, n_] := 
 c/n*Log[c/(E*n)] + (1 - c)*Log[1 - c] - (z*c^2*ep)/2 - (z*c^2*d^2)/
  4 + c/l (p[c, ea, ep, d, l]/2 + Log[1 - p[c, ea, ep, d, l]])

f[c_, ea_, ep_, d_, l_, n_] := 
  Evaluate[D[func[c, ea, ep, d, l, n], c]];

f1[c_, ea_, ep_, d_, l_, n_] := Evaluate[D[f[c, ea, ep, d, l, n], c]];

f2[c_, ea_, ep_, d_, l_, n_] := Evaluate[D[f1[c, ea, ep, d, l, n], c]];

g[c_, ea_, ep_, d_, l_, n_] := 
  Evaluate[D[c/n (1 - p[c, ea, ep, d, l])^(n/l), c]];

Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[{f1[c, ea, ep, d, l, n] == 0, 
   f2[c, ea, ep, d, l, n] == 0, g[c, ea, ep, d, l, n] == 0},
  {c, 0, 1}, {ea, 0, 10},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, Automatic}], {ep, 0, 0}, {d, 0, 2, 2}, {l, 10,
   10, 5}, {n, 100, 100, 10}]
z=6(*hard code this value*)
```

[image]

Comment: epp in the function lmb[c_, ea_, ep_, d_, l_] should be ep

Comment: @demm Thanks. I have edited the question to remove the typo. The issues with the plot still remain. The typo was due to copy-paste and me changing my mind about notation last minute as i was creating this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the PlotPoints (it takes sometime to compute!):

```
    ContourPlot[{f1[c, ea, 0, 0, 10, 100] == 0, f2[c, ea, 0, 0, 10, 100] == 0, g[c, ea, 0, 0, 10, 100] == 0}, {c, 0, 1}, {ea, 0, 10}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, Automatic}, ImageSize -> 500, PlotPoints -> 60]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Increasing the `PlotPoints -> 60` was a definite improvement for `d=0` case and has resolved the jagged edges issue. However, `d!=0`, I don't get a continuous blue curve (which is what I would expect) and instead have two vertical lines. There could perhaps be a different cause for this issue?

Comment: What value of d do you consider?

Comment: In the example I provided in the original question I was looking at `d=2`. But on second thought maybe my expectations were incorrect

Comment: You can see from Plot3D[{f1[c, ea, 0, 2, 10, 100], 0}, {c, 0, 1}, {ea, 0, 10}] that the intersection of f1 with the 0-plane consists of two lines (these are the ones depicted by the contour plot).

Comment: yes, indeed. thanks for your the `PlotPoints` fix. I have accepted and upvoted your answer.